# If else if or Switch case

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Which one is better when performance is taken into consideration an 
**if else if** or **switch case**

Duplicate: [Is there any significant difference between using if/else and switch-case in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/ifelse-vs-switch)

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/ifelse-vs-switch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For both readability and sense use a switch statement instead of loads of IF statements.

The switch statement is slightly faster though:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx (first hit on Google)

The compiler can optimise the switch statement so use that if you have more than, I would say, 3 or 4 different cases

Answer (score 3):

What are you switching on? If you're switching on a string, the C# compiler *either* converts it into a dictionary *or* into a series of if/else checks. Which will be faster depends on the strings in question (including the candidate string).

If you're switching on an integral value, I believe the C# compiler always uses an IL switch statement - but that may or may not be faster than an if/else sequence depending on the values involved. (If they're in a large contiguous block, the CLR can just jump to the right place in the table - if they're very disparate, I suspect it doesn't help.)

Is this just an idle query, or are you really micro-optimising at this level? Any performance difference is going to be insignificant in the vast majority of cases - write for readability.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question of style than performance. Any performance difference will be neglibible, in my opinion. Also, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/ifelse-vs-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/ifelse-vs-switch#).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using int/string/etc, then `switch` has some more complex jump options that might make `switch` more efficient if you have lots of conditions. However, the difference isn't likely to be huge, and `switch` isn't an option for all types (only integer-based, and string).

Answer (score 0):

I've read that switch statements can be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

When addressing performance concerns, you have to measure the difference using realistic data.  The fact that you're asking it from a speculative point of view suggests you don't have an actual performance issue to deal with, and therefore you should worry about which is more readable/maintainable

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, you would have to run tests because if's and switches result in different IL code.

One would hope they were identical.