# When to use the for loop over the while loop?

Tags: c++, c

We can use for loop and while loop for same purpose.
in what means they effect our code if I use for instead of while? same question arises between if-else and switch-case? how to decide what to use?
for example which one you would prefer?

This code:

```
int main()
{
   int n = 10;

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        do_something();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or this code:

```
int main()
{
    int n=10,i=0;

    while(i<n)
    {
          do_something();
          i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if using for or while loop does not effect the code by any means then may I know What was the need to make 2 solution for same problem?

Comment: Removed the C tag as there is no `cin` in C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950931/for-vs-while-in-c-programming

Comment: I slightly altered the title and put the [c] tag back after removing the `cin` as this question certainly spans the entire C/C++ programmer base.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the number of iterations the loop should run beforehand, I would recommend the `for` construct.  While loops are good for when the loop's terminating condition happens at some yet-to-be determined time.

Answer (score 15):

Use whichever one makes the intention of your code clearest.

Answer (score 5):

I try to prefer the `for` loop. Why? Because when I see a `for` loop, I can expect all of the loop bookeeping is kept in a single statement. I can insert `break` or `continue` statements without worrying about breaking how the loop operates. And most importantly, the body of the loop focuses on what you actually want the loop to be doing, rather than maintaining the loop itself. If I see a `while`, then I have to look at and understand the entire loop body before I can understand what iteration pattern the loop uses.

The only place I end up using `while` is for those few cases where the control of the loop is provided by some outside routine (i.e. `FindFirstFileW`)

It's all a matter of personal opinion though. Lots of people don't like what I end up doing with `for` loops because the loop statement often ends up spanning multiple lines.

Comment: can you give some example, where for loop head spans multiple lines?

Comment: +1 for putting the loop bookkeeping all in one place. But I'd say never mix styles—i.e., as soon as *some* of the loop bookkeeping has to happen *inside* the loop body, use a `while` loop; use a `for` loop where everything related to the loop flow is handled in the header. This way, when you see a `for`, as you mention, you are free to use `break` and `continue` without worrying.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a `for` loop might be preferable for simple loops, since the logic of the loop is contained in a single line:

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {...}`

However, sometimes we need more complex logic or flow control.  A `while` loop allows us to implement more complicated loops.  For example, suppose we only want to increment the counter variable under certain conditions:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
{
  if (some_condition) ++i;
  else if (some_other_condition) { ... }
  else break;
}
```

Comment: I don't see this argument. Just replace the first two lines with `for(int i = 0;i < 10;)` and you have the same loop. (And have the bonus of restricting the scope if `i`).

Comment: @Billy ONeal, true - but following that to the extreme we can conclude that `while` is totally superfluous, since any `while (condition)` can be replaced with `for (;condition;)`.  It's subjective, but I think `while` may be a clearer choice if the counter variable is updated conditionally, since someone reading the code usually expects a typical `for` loop to include a (non-conditional) counter-variable update.

Answer (score 2):

There are some very subtle differences..

- scope of loop variable(s), for example, with the `for` loop `i` has local scope, with a `while` this has to be defined before (which means it is available after, of course you can do that with `for` as well..)
- `continue`, with a `for` loop, variable will be increment/decremented, with a `while`, you'd have to insert the operation before `continue`

Frankly, if you need to increment/decrement, a `for` loop makes sense, if you don't know the bounds, and there is no real increment/decrement, a `while` loop makes more sense, e.g.

```
while(some_stream >> input)
{
  // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `while(int i=0, i < n)`; that is, you've to define `i` before the `while` loop; means `i` exists inside as well as outside the loop.

However, in case of `for` loop, you can define `i` right in the `for` loop itself; and so `i` doesn't exist outside the loop. That is one difference. Just because of this difference, I like `for` more than `while`. And use `while` rarely, when `for` makes thing more cumbersome!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the one that makes the code readable and logical.

In some cases the compiler (gcc at least) will be able to optimize a very slightly better than a for loop doing the same thing. If I remember correctly that optimization is only about few clock cycles so it probably never will have any noticeable affect on the performance.

Answer (score 0):

By no means they affect your program the way it works ! Its the matter of ease to understand better.

```
switch(i)     // Once finding your case, you can easily know where the switch ends
              // and thus the next statement of execution
{
    case 1: break ;
    case 2: break ;
    // .....
    case 10: break ;
    default:break ;
}

if( i==1 )   // Here you have the pain of finding where the last else if ends !
{}
else if( i==2)
{}
// ...
else if( i==10)
{}
```

However, it is a matter of taste. I prefer `switch`.

Comment: and what about if-else and switch case

Comment: @Atul As every one suggested it is matter of readability and ease in understanding.

Comment: @Atul: probably the switch is better when you have to test many conditions at the same time.