# How to set while loop counter to start at 1, not 0

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
function listDesserts (){
    var dessertList = ["pudding", "cake", "toffee", "ice cream", "fudge", "nutella"];
    
    var i = 0;
    while (i< dessertList.length){
        var ul = document.getElementById("thelist");
        var nli = document.createElement("li");
        var nliID = 'item-' +i;
        nli.setAttribute('id', nliID);
        nli.setAttribute('class', 'listitem');
        nli.innerHTML = dessertList[i];
        ul.appendChild(nli);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Since I'm setting the li tags IDs based on the number items in my array, `i` sets it to zero as it should.  Rather I want to modify `i` so that it sets the IDs beginning with 1 without it skipping the first array member.  I've tried a few things but I'm missing this.  Anybody?

Comment: Maybe just using `i+1` instead of `i` in the loop body?

Comment: @Uhehesh That should be answer. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are iterating an array, the counter variable should always run from `0` to `length-1`. Other solutions were possible, but are counter-intuitive.

If you have some one-based numberings in that array, just use `i+1` where you need it; in your case `'item-'+(i+1)`.

Btw, you might just use a [`for`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead of `while`.

Comment: that did it, thanks very much.  Questions: what do you mean by "one-based numberings"?  Also, I thought of a for loop but then figured a while loop was more appropriate.  How does one determine the best time to use either construct?

Comment: The opposite of [zero-based numberings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) - wow, Wikipedia really has an article on that term :-)

Comment: [for vs while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950931/for-vs-while-in-c-programming): For array iteration, known number of repeats and other simple conditions usually for-loops are used, they increase readability. I guess it's personal preference, I hardly use while-loops - only when all loop statements don't fit in a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Use   `var i = 1`;

and use `i-1` where you currently have `i`

```
var i = 1;
while (i< dessertList.length-1){
    var ul = document.getElementById("thelist");
    var nli = document.createElement("li");
    var nliID = 'item-' + (i-1);    //<----- here
    nli.setAttribute('id', nliID);
    nli.setAttribute('class', 'listitem');
    nli.innerHTML = dessertList[i-1];    //<----- and here
    ul.appendChild(nli);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `for` is better in this case?

Comment: Should it be `dessertList.length + 1`?

Comment: @codingbiz: your solution skips members of the array.  I  had tried similar things with the same result.