# In CPP, can for replace while and if replace switch?

Tags: c++

I guess every `switch` algorithm can be re-written by `if...else if...else` algorithm, then why do we still need `switch` any more? Is there big differences in ***code efficiency***?

The same question also goes to `for` and `while` loop algorithms.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028437/why-switch-case-and-not-if-else-if?rq=1)

Comment: As you can express roughly the same with different words, you can achieve roughly the same results with different programming language constructs. It is richness of language, bith verbal and programming.

Comment: It's not a matter of code efficiency, but of programmer efficiency. Guess what, you could even rewrite a `for` or a `while` loop with just `if` and `goto` but do **you** really wanna do that? I certainly don't! In the end, the compiler will **always** translate it to an `if/goto` loop anyway since this is pretty much the only available construct in assembly.

Comment: on the `for` vs `while` question you can read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950931/for-vs-while-in-c-programming)