# Counting for loop odd behavior

Tags: c

I have experience in C++ so admittedly this shouldn't be too hard for me to understand but I guess it is. Im learning C from K&R's "The C Programming Language". I am performing this example from Chapter 1 Page 18, the example at the bottom of the page.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
    double nc;
    for(nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f \n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

I am redirecting input from the keyboard to instead be read from a text file (using the '<' when running a.out), and the text file has absolutely nothing in it, not even a newline character.

The program prints a 1. Shouldn't it be 0? Is there a character that is being read that isn't an EOF value? Or is the for loop executing its contents once, then increment by 1, then check the condition?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: can't reproduce https://ideone.com/jwgJCw. Your file is not empty.

Comment: "Is there a character that is being read that isn't an EOF value? " - if you suspect that, what's stopping you from doing something with the result of `getchar()` besides comparing to EOF and throwing it away? Instead, save it to a var, and do something useful like hex-rep print it in the otherwise-empty loop body you have currently.

Comment: @SouXin that isn't true. The increment step never fires if the initial condition expression is false. And it only fires *after* the body (admittedly empty in this case) is iterated first.

Comment: What does `wc -c filename` say?

Comment: @SouXin You can't use a counter as the condition if the end condition is EOF, not a count. His loop syntax is perfectly fine.

Comment: @SouXin you just pasted one of many reasons why cplusplus.com, in a word, *sucks*. That statement is *wrong*. The [description on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) is correct.

Comment: If the standard input provided 0 characters then yes, the program would print 0.  Since it prints 1 instead, it follows that there was one character in the standard input, not zero.  If indeed the standard input was redirected from a file, then that file was not empty.  Even if it contained no newline, perhaps it contained a space character or another non-printable character.

Comment: In Unix *any* file that you create with any common text editor *will* have a sole new line.

Comment: What is the size of the file, as reported by a file browser tool?

Comment: In this case it's more idiomatic to use a `while` loop. Because `for` should only be used when you know when the loop end. You can't know how many time `getchar()` return a valid character. But this don't mater.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is that true of the much used Notepad++? Can Unix files have size 0?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't believe that's true. If you do `vi foo.txt` and just save and quit without doing anything else, it creates a file of 0 bytes.

Comment: @lurker ah, that's true.

Comment: Get a more recent book. K&R rev2 is outdated since 18 years. rev1 should be burried 10m below groundlevel.

Comment: @Stargateur: That is disputable. I don't see a problem with the `for` loop.

Comment: @Olaf this is a question of coding practice I don't want to start a war about this. An answer describe what I mean ["The main difference between the for's and the while's is a matter of pragmatics: we usually use for when there is a known number of iterations, and use while constructs when the number of iterations in not known in advance."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950945/7076153)

Comment: I can provide my test input file as well as my code file if needed. I don't know if there could be a character that I'm just not seeing that is being counted as not being EOF

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I guess `vim` isn't a common editor, then — though it seems pretty commonly used to me.  If I run `vim xx` (where there is no file `xx` in the current directory), and then use `:w` to write the file, it reports: `"xx" [New] 0L, 0C written`, and a subsequent `wc xx` reports `0 0 0 xx`, and `ls -l xx` reports `-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  0 Jun 22 14:25 xx`. That looks like an empty file to me, not a one-line file.

Comment: @MiliainareGryphon: You could change your loop to: `double nc; int c; for (nc = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++nc) printf("%d\n", c);` to see whether the loop body is run.  Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: @Stargateur: That's why I wrote "disputable". If that was the wrong term, I appreciate a better one, I always like to learn. Point is such a comment was not helpful for exactly the reason itt is personal preference.

Comment: The number of characters in a file is never a fractional value, so it would be better to use a long for nc.

Comment: Something tells me your file has a newline.

Comment: The most important thing you can do while *"learning C"* is to **enable compiler warnings** by including at minimum, `-Wall -Wextra` in your compiler string and then do not accept code until it compiles cleanly without warning. (that would most likely have solved your problem here) If not, and you still needed to debug further, See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck...

Comment: one good way to create an empty file on Linux at least is to use the `touch` command, i.e. `touch empty.txt; wc empty.txt
0 0 0 empty.txt`