# Is it okay not to use the local variable i in for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

the code executes fine but the warning still bothers me. I have used the variable `decNumber` we were instructed to use only for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int decNumber,rem=0;

    System.out.print("Enter a decimal number: ");
    decNumber = in.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;decNumber>0;i++) {


                rem = (decNumber%2);
                decNumber = (decNumber/2);
                System.out.println(rem);


    }
```

Comment: Were you assuming that we could all see your screen?  _What_ warning?

Comment: Sure, but wouldn't a `while-loop` or `do-while` loop be better?

Comment: sorry. i'm new here. forgot to mention where the warning was. it's found in the conditional expression in the for loop. It says "The value of the local variable i is not used. I was just wondering if it's okay neglect it.

Comment: The warning makes a good point.  What's the point of defining `i`?  If you think you have to have an `i` in order to have a loop, then (1) you can have `for` loops with empty parts, so you could just delete `int i = 0` and `i++` (but not the semicolons), and (2) if you don't need a variable like `i`, then your loop is in essence a `while` loop (but I see that you weren't suppose to use one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be a bit more kosher:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int decNumber = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = decNumber; i > 0; i = i / 2) {
            int rem = (i % 2);
            System.out.println(rem);
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

The advantages here are

1. You don't destroy the `decNumber` variable, so it can still be used later on
2. The `for` loop keeps internal behaviour (i.e. `rem`) from bleeding out
3. The `for` loop is actually used like a for instead of a `while`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add the warning but I am sure that doesn't matter, considering context of your question.

You must know the difference between a `for` and `while` loop. A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950931/for-vs-while-in-c-programming).

In your code, you're not using the local variable `i` to control your loop. Your loop is controlled by `decNumber>0`, so `for` is totally unnecessary here.

A better way is to use `while`

```
while ( decNumber > 0 ) {
    rem = (decNumber%2);
    decNumber = (decNumber/2);
    System.out.println(rem);
}
```

Comment: yes that's what i thought also but since my instructor wanted us to use for loop maybe I'll find another way for i. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're not using `i` at all.  In fact, `decNumber` is serving as the iteration index, because it's the thing that changes from one iteration of the loop to the next.  You have lines in your code that perform the functions of all three parts of a `for` loop -

- initialisation: `int decNumber = in.nextInt();`
- continuation condition: `decNumber > 0`
- increment: `decNumber = decNumber / 2`, which you can also write as `decNumber /= 2`.

Note also that since you only use `rem` inside the loop, it's better to declare it inside the loop, than right at the beginning.

Putting all this together, you can remain in the spirit of a `for` loop, by rewriting your code as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a decimal number: ");
    for( int decNumber = in.nextInt(); decNumber > 0; decNumber /= 2 ) {
         int rem = decNumber % 2;
         System.out.println(rem);
    }
}
```

This makes it clear how your loop is initialised, what the condition is that makes it continue, and what changes from one iteration to the next; so is better for readability than using a redundant index variable.