# How to refactor a chain of if-else statements into a single line

Tags: c++, if-statement

How to do if i want to get this code into one line?

```
if (count >= 0 && count <= 199) {
    return 1;
} else if (count >= 200 && count <= 399) {
    return 2;
} else if (count >= 400 && count <= 599) {
    return 3;
} else if (count >= 600 && count <= 799) {
    return 4;
} else {
    return 5;
}
```

I'm just figuring is there any shortcut for this few line of codes.

Comment: I'd recommend a switch statement to eliminate the multiple if/else.

Comment: literally `return 1` as in value 1??

Comment: @devlincarnate: o'really? how??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Google switch statement?  For example:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm

Comment: @devlincarnate: If you didn't get the point of my comment, try to write this code with switches. I'm serious.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - two comments.  first, when I made my original comment, this question didn't have a tag and no indication of language.  So my comment was a general one.  second, I fail to see what the trouble would be in using a switch statement with that code.  switch(count) followed by the comparisons and returns.  In the languages I'm familiar with, [it is preferable to avoid multiple if/else and use a switch statement instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else).  Apparently you have a differing opinion, which is fine.

Comment: @devlincarnate: You fail to see it because you didn't write code and test it. There's an opportunity to learn something here.

Comment: @devlincarnate C++ switch statements don't work the way you seem to think.

Comment: @devlincarnate "No indication of language"... Try reading the title sometime.

Comment: As a side note, the structure he's given could leave out all of the `else`s since each clause `return`s

Comment: @BenVoigt - you're right.  it was in the title and i missed it.  oh well... with less than 4 hours of sleep last night, perhaps an oversight is warranted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return ( count >= 0 && count <= 799 ) ? (1 + count / 200) : 5;`

That is: if count is in range, you are returning successive values for each span of 200, and if it is out of range, you are returning 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't compute the range directly from the count as shown in Scott Hunter's answer (e.g., if the ranges aren't uniformly sized or the values they map to don't form a simple pattern), you can encapsulate a little table lookup like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int FindRange(int count) {
  static const std::pair<int, int> ranges[] = {
    {   0, 5 },
    { 200, 1 },
    { 400, 2 },
    { 600, 3 },
    { 800, 4 }
  };
  const auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(ranges), std::end(ranges),
                               [=](const std::pair<const int, int> &range) {
                                 return count < range.first;
                               });
  return (it == std::end(ranges)) ? ranges[0].second : it->second;
}
```

You can then change the table values and, as long as you keep them sorted, this function will continue to work.

It's a linear search through the table, so it should be on-par with the performance of a cascaded if-else.

Answer (score 0):

```
return 1 + std::min(count, 800) / 200;
```

should do. The `if` is hidden in `std::min`. If `count` is larger than 800, it is replaced by 800, and `std::min(count, 800) / 200` is equal to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, such if-else chains can be replaced with the conditional operator:

```cpp
return count >=   0 && count <= 199 ? 1
     : count >= 200 && count <= 399 ? 2
     : count >= 400 && count <= 599 ? 3
     : count >= 600 && count <= 799 ? 4
                                    : 5;
```

However, in this particular case, you can also write:

```cpp
return count / 200 + 1;
```

Or, if you are worried about `count` falling outside the acceptable range of values, you can "clamp" it:

```cpp
return std::min(std::max(count / 200 + 1, 1), 5);
```