# php too many if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have php code as below:

```
if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Ubud_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Ubud_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
    if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Tanah_Lot_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Tanah_Lot_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
    if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Sanur_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Sanur_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
    if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Seminyak_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Seminyak_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
    if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Kuta_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Kuta_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
    if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Jimbaran_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Jimbaran_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
    if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Nusa_Dua_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
        $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Nusa_Dua_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
    }
// many code over 1,000
```

How can i optimize it ?
I want the page run faster, now is too slow for it.

Comment: try a switch statement (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: You should do a function that swaps the two parts of the strings that change and then you don't need any if/else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, SWITCH CASE should be better.

go through this...

[Why the switch statement and not if-else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else)

[Is "else if" faster than "switch() case"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case)

give a try to this,

```
switch ($ptp_car_1){   
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Ubud_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Ubud_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Tanah_Lot_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Tanah_Lot_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Sanur_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Sanur_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Seminyak_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Seminyak_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Kuta_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Kuta_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Jimbaran_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Jimbaran_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;
        case "ptp_Denpasar_Nusa_Dua_fee_".$way."_car_1":
        {
             $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Nusa_Dua_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
        }
        break;

        /*
        //OPTIONAL

        default:
            $ptp_car_1 = $ptp_car_1;

        */   


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This function will directly convert the strings as long as the other 1000+ strings follow the same pattern.

```
// reorder parts if the following pattern is true for all entries
//
// starts with "ptp" (store as group 1)
// then contains an '_'
// then has at least 1 char that is not an '_' (store as group 2)
// then contains an '_'
// then contains at least 1 char that is not '_fee_' (store as group 3)
// then contains an '_'
// then contains any number of chars (store as group 4)
//
// group 4 will contain 'fee_', $way and '_car_1' but we really don't need to care what
// those chars are, they just get tacked on to the end.
// 
// Once the original is broken up, parts 2 & 3 are swapped and the 
// results are imploded into the desired string with '_' separators.
//
function swapPtpParts($ptp_car_1) {
    $matches = [];
    if(preg_match("/(ptp)_([^_]+)_(.+?(?=_fee_))_(.*)/", $ptp_car_1, $matches)) {
        $parts = [
            $matches[1],
            $matches[3],
            $matches[2],
            $matches[4],
        ];
        return implode('_', $parts);
    }
    return $ptp_car_1;    
}
```

Usage:

```
$ptp_car_1 = swapPtpParts($ptp_car_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use else if like below:

```
if($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Ubud_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Ubud_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
elseif($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Tanah_Lot_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Tanah_Lot_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
elseif($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Sanur_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Sanur_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
elseif($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Seminyak_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Seminyak_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
elseif($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Kuta_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Kuta_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
elseif($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Jimbaran_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Jimbaran_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
elseif($ptp_car_1 == "ptp_Denpasar_Nusa_Dua_fee_".$way."_car_1"){
    $ptp_car_1 = "ptp_Nusa_Dua_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1";
}
```

It would be faster.

Comment: *Change it to `echo "done";` even faster!* Just changing the intention of a code to make it faster is useless

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen all 1000 if statements but if the patten holds, you can use a function that replaces the text for you.  As before:

```
function convertDenpansarFeeString($ptp_car, $way)
{
    // number of characters in ptp_Denpasar_ = 13
    // number of characters in _car_ = 5
    return "ptp_"
        . substr($ptp_car
            , 13
            , strpos($ptp_car, "_fee_") - 13
        )
        . "_Denpasar_fee_"
        . $way
        . "_car_"
        . substr($ptp_car
            , strpos($ptp_car, "_car_") + 5
        );
}
```

And use like so:

```
$ptp_car1 = convertDenpansarFeeString($ptp_car1, $way);
$ptp_car2 = convertDenpansarFeeString($ptp_car2, $way);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using array ?

```
function getResult($key){
    $way = 'hello';
    $array = [
        'ptp_Denpasar_Ubud_fee_'.$way.'_car_1' => "ptp_Ubud_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1",
        "ptp_Denpasar_Tanah_Lot_fee_".$way."_car_1" => "ptp_Sanur_Denpasar_fee_".$way."_car_1",
    ];
    return $array[$key];
}

echo getResult('ptp_Denpasar_Ubud_fee_hello_car_1');
```