# Why can I use only one "while" loop in my code?

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I am writing a program in C++, and I want the user to make a choice between a few options, and each option is different. At the end of the option, I want the user to be able to select a different option from a menu, but if the user originally chooses option 3, when the user gets back to the menu, if he/she chooses 1 or 2 it terminates the program. What can I do to make the code repeat itself?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int play;
   cout << "What do you want to do now?" << endl;
   cout << "Choose a number..." << endl;
   cout << "1) Talk." << endl;
   cout << "2) Vent." << endl;
   cout << "3) Play a guessing game." << endl;
   cout << "4) End." << endl;
   cin >> play;

   while (play == 1){
      //code here
      cout << "What do you want to do now?" << endl;
      cout << "Choose a number..." << endl;
      cout << "1) Talk." << endl;
      cout << "2) Vent." << endl;
      cout << "3) Play a guessing game." << endl;
      cout << "4) End." << endl;
      cin >> play;
   }

   while (play == 2){
      //code goes here
      cout << "What do you want to do now?" << endl;
      cout << "Choose a number..." << endl;
      cout << "1) Talk." << endl;
      cout << "2) Vent." << endl;
      cout << "3) Play a guessing game." << endl;
      cout << "4) End." << endl;
      cin >> play;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: search for `switch()` and put it in one `while()` loop

Comment: Not sure what you expected. You have written no code to show the menu again when the user entered `3`.

Comment: It was just a small piece of the code. Thank you for the feedback though. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do something like this is to put your entire code in a `while (true)` loop, and break out of when the user chooses to exit, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int play;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "What do you want to do now?" << endl;
        cout << "Choose a number..." << endl;
        cout << "1) Talk." << endl;
        cout << "2) Vent." << endl;
        cout << "3) Play a guessing game." << endl;
        cout << "4) End." << endl;
        cin >> play;

        if (play == 1)
        {
            // code for Talk...
        }
        else if (play == 2)
        {
            // code for Vent...
        }
        else if (play == 3)
        {
            // code for Play a guessing game....
        }
        else if (play == 4)
        {
             // End
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Expected a number between 1 and 4" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I have also added a test for unrecognised input
**EDIT** You can also use a switch statement, if you prefer the syntax (make sure you don't have fall through unless you really want it)
(Note: both codes are equivalent and will probably produce identical assembly)

```
int main() 
{
    int play;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "What do you want to do now?" << endl;
        cout << "Choose a number..." << endl;
        cout << "1) Talk." << endl;
        cout << "2) Vent." << endl;
        cout << "3) Play a guessing game." << endl;
        cout << "4) End." << endl;
        cin >> play;

    switch (play)
    {
    case 1:
        // code for Talk...
        break;
    case 2:
        // code for Vent...
        break;
    case 3:
        // code for Play a guessing game....
        break;
    case 4:
        // End
        return 0;
    default:
        std::cout << "Expected a number between 1 and 4" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of a "switch" statement?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, I tend not to use them, and I certainly wouldn't suggest them to a (potentially) novice programmer. A set of `else if` statements is much easier to understand, and has a nice syntax.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Have you ever heard of "shush"?

Answer (score 0):

A fancy way to do this is using `switch()` and here is [**Why the switch statement and not if-else?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else) A `switch()` can help your program get rid of having a very long nested if-else statements. Look how much beautiful its:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int play = 0;

    while (play != 4)
    {
        std::cout << "What do you want to do now?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Choose a number..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1) Talk." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2) Vent." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3) Play a guessing game." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4) End." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> play;

        switch (play)
        {
            case 1: // code for talk here
                break;
            case 2: // code for Vent
                break;
            case 3: // code for Play
                break;
            case 4: std::cout << "program will exits!";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So instead of "a very long nested if-else statements _[sic]_" you have a very long nested switch statement and all the oddities therein, for no reason. Ace.

Comment: @light I just dream about `switch()` at night. I would take a 30 switch statement and understand it better than three if-else statements.

Comment: Well please keep your fetishes to yourself. You are in a position of "teacher" right now and have a certain responsibility!

Comment: @light I am great teacher and you are free to set an objection. The max you can do?

Comment: @ligh appologies for setting a personal opinion here anyway :)