# When to use if-else loop and switch loop

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement

I am new to java, so want to understand which statement to be used and when ?

Program has a condition where there are three checks needs to be done.
I am not clear which statement to go for.

Please help me in understanding the statement usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the switch statement and not if-else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is normally used if you just check one or more different conditions that can be connected with logical operators like `and` and `or`.

```java
//if the color is red or blue
if (color == 'red' | color == 'blue' {
    //do something.
}
```

The `switch` statement can be used if you have one condition that has to be handled different, depending on its value.

```java
//do different things depending on the color
switch (color) {
    case 'red':
        //do something
        break;
    case 'blue':
        //do something else
        break;
}
```