# Writing JQuery / Javascript IF / else statement using Hidden Field Values as

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hidden

I'm trying to get a div to be assigned a CSS class based on the value of a hidden field that is loaded via ajax.

My code returns the proper value for the hidden field when called, but my div is always assigned the same css class, regardless of the result.

I'm guessing something is wrong with my IF statement syntax:

```
function doneLoading(){

var colorStatus = $('#colorStatus').val();

if(colorStatus = 'RED'){
    $('.circleFrame').addClass('redState'); 
}

else if(colorStatus = 'GREEN'){
    $('.circleFrame').addClass('greenState');   
}

else if(colorStatus = 'YELLOW'){
    $('.circleFrame').addClass('yellowState');  
}

else {
    alert("Something is broken");
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, check out the `switch` function....`switch(colorStatus){case 'RED': do something; break; case 'GREEN': do something else; break;}`

Comment: We were talking about the switch function (c) in class today. What benefits does it have over the if?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241768/switch-vs-if-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator.

Try

```
if(colorStatus === 'RED'){
    $('.circleFrame').addClass('redState'); 
}
```

instead. (And similarly for the other colours.)

Comment: Thank you! What's the difference between == and === ?

Comment: @apttap Yep. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use :)

Answer (score 5):

It's because you're doing `=` assignment instead of `==` comparison. You may want to use http://jshint.com to help locate these sorts of bugs.

Consider the following alternative to shorten your code.

```
function doneLoading() {
    var color = $('#colorStatus').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.circleFrame').addClass(color + 'State');
}
```

---

To maintain the validation, you could do this:

```
var colors = {green:1, red:1, yellow:1};

function doneLoading() {
    var color = $('#colorStatus').val().toLowerCase();

    if (colors.hasOwnProperty(color))
        $('.circleFrame').addClass(color + 'State');
    else
        alert("Something is broken");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a lot smarter than what I was doing. Unfortunately I need to keep the states separated from this specific value (other values could cause a change of colorState). Great idea though.

Comment: @apttap: Alrighty, but FYI if you need a little validation, you can put this outside the function `var colors = {green:1, red:1, yellow:1};` and then before you assign the class, you can do `if (colors.hasOwnProperty(color)) { /*change the class*/ } else { /*throw an error*/ }`