# php - benefits of conditions - switch over if-then

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch vs if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241768/switch-vs-if-statements)

In a very simple php scenario, what are the benefits (if any) of :

```
function foo_1($bar){
  if $bar == 'yes'{
  return 'yes';
  } 
// or the use of 'else'
 if $bar == 'no'{
 return 'no';
  }
}
```

against :

```
function foo_2($bar){
 switch ($bar) {
    case 'yes' :
     return 'yes';
    break;

    case 'no' :
     return 'no';
    break; 
    }
  }
}
```

(SIDENOTE : I know that if we have multiple conditions ( if ($bar=='yes') && ($bar !='else')..) that might be a reason, but also in that scenario, one can have case with conditions inside ..)

Comment: Been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241768/switch-vs-if-statements

Comment: ... Or you need to get out more. But then again the boyfriend is asleep and my daughter is asleep. Her mothers are also asleep.

Comment: Don't lose time on this kind of optimization, it's useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of preference, since both **if** and **switch** can provide the same functionality. I'd ask myself which option makes your code more readable.