# Excel VBA weird error while opening another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script which copies some rows from thisworkbook to other.
Multiple people use this file. file does not have any password protection.
code:

```
dim xbook as workbook
path = "xbook.xlsx"
xbook = WorkBooks.open("path", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
```

Problem:
For me its running fine but for some people the file xbook needs to be opened beforehand to run the code. For at least one other person the xbook needs to be closed to run the code.

Tried changing path , UpdateLinks to false/true not working

Comment: It needs to be `Set xbook = ...`. Other than that: As you don't specify the path: Are you sure the workbook is always available? And what happens if it doesn't *"run fine"*?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a workbook can be tricky.
Workbook can be:

1. Already opened and hidden
2. Already opened and visible
3. Closed

When it is opened - use only a filename like `"xbook.xlsx"`. When closed - use the full path, e.g. `"D:/Projects/One/xbook.xlsx"`.

Here is a function I constantly use:

```
Public Function OpenExcelWorkbook(fullPath$, Optional bVisible As Boolean = False, Optional bReadOnly As Boolean = True) As Workbook
    Dim wbName$
    Dim bIsOpen As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    ' read file name from the full path
    wbName = GetFileName(fullPath)
    
    ' detect if the file is open
    ' (1) usual way - by accessing file
    bIsOpen = IsFileOpen(fullPath)
    ' (2) SAP way - when SAP opens Excel file externally (in new Application).
    If bIsOpen = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = GetObject(wbName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then bIsOpen = True
    End If
    
    ' open / assign
    If bIsOpen = True Then
        Set OpenExcelWorkbook = Workbooks(wbName)
    Else
        
        If bVisible = True Then
            Set OpenExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fullPath, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=bReadOnly)
        Else
            ' open it as hidden: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65848600/8524164
            Set OpenExcelWorkbook = GetObject(fullPath)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

' helper functions

```
Function GetFileName(strFullPath As String) As String
    ' forked from:
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/19192897/8524164
    GetFileName = Right(strFullPath, Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, Application.PathSeparator))
End Function

Function IsFileOpen(tempFileName As String) As Boolean
    'Check if a file is locally open
    Dim ff     As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open tempFileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ErrNo = 70 Then IsFileOpen = True
End Function
```

In your case that would be something like:

```
set xbook  = OpenExcelWorkbook("D:/Projects/One/xbook.xlsx", True, False)
```

And of course check if the workbook is *really* located on the path specified.
*Edit*: updated per Tim Williams' comment

```
Public Function IsFileExist(strFullPath) As Boolean   
   IsFileExist = Len(Dir(strFullPath)) > 0
End Function
```

---

The final line is:

```
if IsFileExist("D:/Projects/One/xbook.xlsx") then
  set xbook  = OpenExcelWorkbook("D:/Projects/One/xbook.xlsx", True, False)
end if
```

Comment: The `select case` could be replaced with an `if`.

Comment: And maybe `IsFileExist = Len(Dir(strFullPath)) > 0`

Comment: @Tim Williams, yes, totally. Didn't update the code for a long time.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, that's a matter of readability. It does not make a big difference in 'small' executions. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11640413/8524164

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov `If ErrNo = 70 Then IsFileOpen = True` reduces it from 4 lines to 1. You should probably get rid of the magic number as well with a constant.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, you're absolutely correct! I initially forked this from another project where the error number was significant. It serves no purpose in this function. I appreciate this unexpected improvements :)

I share your idea about avoiding 'magic numbers,' but didn't find a class for errors in VBA. There's a list of errors and messages on MS but no reference to the object model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa264975(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. 
If you can share how to convert it to more explicit code, I'd be grateful.