# c# How to make this code more efficient than a case scenario

Tags: c#, case

I'm coding a simple fruit machine and this is one of my methods, I was wondering if it was possible to make this code more efficient: (Before using case i had it an if / else if statement)

_intNudgeCount gets a number between 0 - 9 hence the case.

```
public void DrawNudgeCount()
    {
        switch (_intNudgeCount)
        {
            case 9:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._9;
                break;
            case 8:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._8;
                break;
            case 7:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._7;
                break;
            case 6:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._6;
                break;
            case 5:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._5;
                break;
            case 4:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._4;
                break;
            case 3:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._3;
                break;
            case 2:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._2;
                break;
            case 1:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._1;
                break;
            case 0:
                pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = Properties.Resources._0;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

SOLVED:

It's okay, I've got it down to 3 lines of code:

//declare resource images at top of the class.

```
private System.Drawing.Image[]  _arrayNudgeCount;
```

//Populated the array when loading the class.

```
_arrayNudgeCount = new System.Drawing.Image[] { Properties.Resources._0, Properties.Resources._1};
```

//Redraw images

```
public void DrawNudgeCount()
{
pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = _arrayNudgeCount[_intNudgeCount];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you take a look a this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case

Comment: I done something similar to that before, i'm trying to cut down the amount of lines of code I have, or is this the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: @user2302941 Remove the question or add your solution and accept it.

Comment: Add it as an answer, not a comment. =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have reduced it to just one line of code I were you!

```
pictureBoxNudgeCount.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + _intNudgeCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

place your Image in a folder beside of your appilication and call pictureBoxNudgeCount.Load(ConstantSectionPath+_intNudgeCount+".jpg");   if jpg is your file extensions.