# items in GridLayoutManager (RecyclerView) changes position on scroll android

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

**What I have**

I have a `GridLayoutManager (RecyclerView)` that has **position 0,2,5,7** fixed with custom images (relative layout converted to bitmaps) & rest positions are filled with server images

**My problem**

When I scroll the items in the layout changes its position

**My code**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProfilePhotosViewHolder ProfilePhotosViewHolder, final int position) {
        model = list.get(position);

        if (position == 0 || position == 2 || position == 5 || position == 7) {
            if (position == 0) {
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredHeight());
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.buildDrawingCache(true);
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getDrawingCache());
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ......

            }

            if (position == 5) {
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               ......
            }

            if (position == 7) {
                ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativePosts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ......
            }

        } else {

            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativePosts.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageUrl(model.ImagesUri, imageLoader);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.im_profile_monuments);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.im_profile_monuments);
        }
```

**Screen shot**
[image]

**After scrolling**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the **recycling mechanism**, while you're playing with visibility, you also need to handle the visibility of the other `View`s in each `if` block.

eg for position 2:

```
if (position == 2) {

    ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativePosts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**PS:** I suggest you to use `switch(position)` instead of nested `if` blocks.

Comment: any advantage of switch over if in my case ?

Comment: @karthikkolanji : Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case. It's about how it's implemented internally. And yes, +1 for prettier code :)