# C++ switch statement evaluation

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Assume we have a following code:

```
switch (currentChar) {
    case 'G':
    case 'T':                   
    case 'M':
    case ';':                       
    case '\r':                      
    case '\n':  
        doSomething();      
        break;
}
```

If the first condition is met (`currentChar == 'G'`) are the following cases also compared, or the program jumps straight to `doSomething()`?

What would be faster to execute: the switch-case, or an if with `||` operator?

**Clarification:**
I want `doSomething` to be executed if any of the conditions is met. I also know that the 'G' case will occur in some 99% of all cases. Can I assume that it will be compared as the first if I put it on top of the list?

Comment: Following statements are also evaluated, until they meet a `break;` statement or fall off the switch statement.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The cases are constant expressions, and it does not make one bit of difference whether those constant expressions are evaluated. Are you asking if `currentChar` is compared to those case values? Are you asking if `doSomething()` is evaluated? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: You can test each way and find out yourself.  Generally Which way is faster questions are too broad as they can depended on many different factors.

Comment: @hvd I'm asking if the `currentChar` is compared to those case values.

Comment: @mactro Okay. So you know that `doSomething()` will be called, and you're wondering, when `currentChar == 'G'`, if `currentChar == 'T'`, `currentChar == 'M'`, `currentChar == ';'`, etc. are pointlessly evaluated just to ignore their results. Is that right? In that case,  the very first answer you got (@πάνταῥεῖ's) probably covers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the first condition is met `(currentChar == 'G')` are the following cases also evaluated, or the program jumps straight to `doSomething()`?

It will immediately jump to execute `doSomething()`

> What would be faster to execute: the switch-case, or an if with `||` operator?

I don't think it would make any difference with any decent modern c++ compiler, and the emitted code should be fairly the same.

Comment: Check the answer I gave. I wrote a program and it was faster using an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be faster to execute: the switch-case, or an if with || operator?

Go for `switch()`. If you have an enum or integer with small value set, `switch()` will usually create a jump table.

Answer (score 1):

Once `currentChar`is compared to `'G'`, instructions jump to instruction `doSomething()`. You cannot rely on order of your cases to *"optimize"* the `switch`.

Note that comparison is not necessary sequential.
`switch` may be implemented as jump table for example:

```
void foo_switch(char c)
{
    switch (c) {
        case '0': bar0(); break;        
        case '1': bar1(); break;        
        case '2': bar2(); break;        
        case '3': bar3(); break;        
    };
}

void foo_if(char c)
{
    if (c == '0') {
        bar0();
    } else if (c == '1') {
        bar1();
    } else if (c == '2') {
        bar2();
    } else if (c == '3') {
        bar3();
    }
}

void foo_table(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '3') {
        using voidFPtr = void(*)();
        voidFPtr funcs[] = {&bar0, &bar1, &bar2, &bar3};
        funcs[c - '0']();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi what do you mean by "_comparison is not necessary sequential.
_" and could you please provide a basic design of a jump table?

Answer (score 1):

Questions about the performance outcome of a particular style of code are almost always a waste of time.

Here's how gcc5.3 deals with this code after an optimisation pass:

```
test(char):
        cmpb    $59, %dil
        je      .L3      
        jle     .L6       
        cmpb    $77, %dil
        je      .L3
        cmpb    $84, %dil
        je      .L3
        cmpb    $71, %dil
        je      .L3
.L1:
        rep ret
.L6:
        cmpb    $10, %dil
        je      .L3
        cmpb    $13, %dil
        jne     .L1
.L3:
        jmp     doSomething()
```

I really don't think you could write anything faster without creating a 256-entry jump table, which would have its own consequences in terms of cache locality and exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

> If the first condition is met (currentChar == 'G') are the following cases also evaluated, or the program jumps straight to doSomething()?

In your example, it will straight away jump to `doSomething()`.  In case you don't want to have this behavior, then you need to insert `break` statements as shown for one case below:

```
switch (currentChar) {
    case 'G': /*things to be done */ break /* This break will take it out of switch*/;
    case 'T':                   
    case 'M':
    case ';':                       
    case '\r':                      
    case '\n':  
        doSomething();      
        break;
}
```

Also, note that in your example, `break` is not needed, as it is the last statement of your switch statement.  Please refer [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) link for a working example of switch statement.

> What would be faster to execute: the switch-case, or an if with || operator?

Assuming that you are using a decent compiler, the difference is minimum so that it can be ignored.  Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case) So link, in case you need to know more specifics.

**Edit for your clarification**:

> I want `doSomething()` to be executed if any of the conditions is met.

Yes, as per your code, `doSomething()` would be executed even if only one of the conditions is met.

> I also know that the 'G' case will occur in some 99% of all cases. Can I assume that it will be compared as the first if I put it on top of the list?

The remaining cases won't be checked.

Comment: break there is needed, not for proper compilation though.

Comment: @Slava sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: it is better to put `break` into last statement, on one side compiler will ignore that, on another - when you add another label after the last one you will not get surprises. IE it is too easy to create a bug when there is no break.

Answer (score 0):

> If the first condition is met (currentChar == 'G') are the following
>   cases also evaluated, or the program jumps straight to doSomething()?

It falls through until it finds a `break` or hits the end.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be faster to execute: the switch-case, or an if with || operator?

You should worry about code readability and supportability, so use whatever is more readable for you. Then if you have issue with program speed work on optimization.

For readability - of course that's subjective, but with switch you get less verbose code, as you do not have to repeat variable name multiple times:

```
if( currentChar == 'G' || currentChar == 'B' || currentChar == 'C' )
```

so I would prefer switch in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (currentChar) {
    case 'G':
    case 'T':                   
    case 'M':
    case ';':                       
    case '\r':                      
    case '\n':  
        doSomething();      
        break;
}
```

This makes `doSomething()` be called if `currentChar` is `G`, `T`, `M`, `;`, `\r` or `\n`. It's faster to use a `switch` than just plain `if`, because `switch` statements are often optimized into jump tables. This is why a switch must operate on a constant integral value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee for the order of checking in a switch case. There is also no guarantee for the order of execution of `||` if there are no side effects for the expressions.
Basically, if the only difference is timing, c++ guarantees nothing about the order of stuff, on the basis of the as-if rule.

Comment: `a || b` is short circuiting and guaranteed to not evaluate `b` if `a` evaluated to true (unless you overload it of course). `5.15 [expr.log.or]`

Comment: @user975989: as I said, if a and b have no side effects, the as-if rule allows the compiler to implement the operator in any way that produces the same result