# Custom Ordering in C#

Tags: c#

There is a list of `Package` item is sorted by `GUID`, but I need to order them as follows

`KK %, AB, AB art, DD %, FV, ER, PP and WW`

I have implemented as follows, but I wonder is there a better way of doing it?

```
List<PackageType> list = new List<PackageType> (8);           
foreach (var a in mail.Package)
{
 if (a.Name == "KK %")
    list[0] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "AB art")
    list[1] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "AB")
    list[2] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "DD %")
    list[3] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "FV")
    list[4] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "ER")
    list[5] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "PP")
    list[6] = a;
 else if (a.Name == "WW")
   list[7] = a;
}
```

Comment: You do realize "DD" is in there twice, right? Also, this is the most random ordering scheme I have ever seen. Probably needs a custom comparer that would more or less be those if statements

Comment: Is there a hidden logic behind that order?

Comment: It was just typo, I have corrected

Comment: @Marco There is unfortunately, no logic behind that.

Comment: you could use `switch case` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case

Comment: Maybe put an Order value in your Package class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this down to two lines (one for array definition, one for ordering):

```
var PackageOrder = new[] { "KK %", "AB", "AB art", "DD %", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW"};

//...

var list =  mail.Package.OrderBy(p => Array.IndexOf(PackageOrder, p.Name)).ToList();
```

But we can do even better.

The code so far either requires several O(n) lookups into the reference array, or switching to a `Dictionary<string,int>`, which is O(1) for each lookup for a value of `1` that might be disproportionate to the task. Each package item may need several of these lookups over the course of a sort operation, which means this might be less efficient than you want.

We can get around that like this:

```
private static string[] Names = new[] { "KK", "AB", "BC", "DD", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW" };

//...

var list =  mail.Package.
           Select(p => new {Package = p, Index = Array.IndexOf(Names, p.Name)}).
           OrderBy(p => p.Index).
           Select(p => p.Package).ToList();
```

This guarantees only one lookup per package over the course of the sort. The idea is to first create a projection of the original data that also includes an index, then sort by the index, and finally project back to just the original data. Now the only question is whether to use an array or dictionary, which mainly depends on the size of the reference array (for this size data stick with the array, for more than about 15 items, switch to the dictionary; but it varies depending on the `GetHashCode()` performance of your type).

Of course, there's also YAGNI to consider. For large sets this will typically be much better, but for small data it might not be worth it, or if the data happens to be sorted in a certain lucky ways it can make things slower. It can also make things slower if your are more constrained by memory pressure than cpu time (common on web servers). But in the general sense, it's a step in the right direction.

Finally, I question the need for an actual `List<T>` here. Just change the declaration to `var` and remove the `.ToList()` at the end. Wait to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` until you absolutely need it, and work with the simple `IEnumerable<T>` until then. This can often greatly improve performance.

In this case (and for reference, I added this paragraph later on), it seems like you only have eight items total, meaning the extra code isn't really saving you anything. With that in mind, I'd just stick with the two-line solution at the top of this answer (when performance doesn't matter, go for less or simpler code).

Comment: If I apply the following , it does not return the right order. any idea ? `var names = new[] { "KK %", "AB", "AB art", "DD %", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW" };`

Comment: If you're going for an SQL-style LIKE match, you'll need something a bit different than Array.IndexOf

Comment: Could you please give an example what I could use?

Comment: I've gone home... On my phone now. Hard to do more code from here.

Comment: @hotspring Home now. Looking at this again, I'm not sure anymore that even adding rudimentary LIKE support will be good enough. Is this a 1:1 mapping, or might there be more than 8 Package items? Are you trying to condense the results into 7 buckets?

Comment: Package is not more than 8 items.

Answer (score 6):

```
// List<PackageType> list = ...;
var names = new[] { "KK", "AB", "BC", "DD", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW" };
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(packageType => Array.IndexOf(names, packageType.Name));
```

Here's a longer version of the above that explains in more detail what's going on:

```
// this array contains all recognized keys in the desired order;
private static string[] Names = new[] { "KK", "AB", "BC", "DD", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW" };

// this helper method will return the index of a `PackageType`'s `Name`
// in the above array, and thus a key by which you can sort `PackageType`s.
static int GetSortingKey(PackageType packageType)
{
    var sortingKey = Array.IndexOf(Names, packageType.Name);
    if (sortingKey == -1) throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    return sortingKey;
}

// this is how you could then sort your `PackageType` objects:
// List<PackageType> list = ...;
IEnumerable<PackageType> sortedList = list.OrderBy(GetSortingKey);
```

Comment: Maybe just use Enum for each name? then sort by enum

Comment: @Imants: I don't make the rules. :) I tried to stay as close to what the OP's got as I can.

Comment: `OrderBy(packageType => SortingKeyFor(packageType))` can be condensed to `OrderBy(SortingKeyFor)`

Comment: Or: `list.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(x))`

Comment: If I apply the following , it does not return the right order. any idea ? `var names = new[] { "KK %", "AB", "AB art", "DD %", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW" };`

Answer (score 2):

Updated version of @stakx answer. Well I think this should be better solution, if these values are fixed, also can be used elsewhere. Each value in enum has its int value, by which they can be ordered.

```
public enum Names 
{
   KK, //0
   AB, //1
   BC, //2
   DD, //3
   FV, //4
   ER, //5
   PP, //6
   WW //7
}

var packageList = list.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
```

**UPDATE**

Use example for enum in class

```
public class Package 
{
   public Names Name { get; set; }
}
```

If there is need to get string value of this enum, then just use this

`Package package` - Package class variable

```
package.Name.ToString();
```

If you need whole list of enum names (enum key names), you can use `Enum` class method:

> `Enum.GetNames(Type enumType)` which returns string array with all defined enum key names.

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Names))
```

Comment: *If* the OP is willing to re-declare his `PackageType.Name` property to this type (instead of `string`), this would admittedly be a lot simpler.

Comment: @stakx well you can get string value from enum and vica versa

Comment: You definitely can, but it might not be as efficient as expected. (`Enum` methods are often surprisingly inefficent due to them involving reflection. But I might be wrong in this specific case.) Either way, I like your suggested solution.

Comment: @ImantsVolkovs How do you use Enum in your solution?. you declare it but where do you use?

Comment: @hotspring you can use this solution if you can somehow declare the `.Name` property as the enum type instead of string.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative.. (I haven't compiled it)

```
var indexPositions = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    { "KK", 0 },
    { "AB", 1 },
    { "BC", 2 },
    { "DD", 3 },
    { "FV", 4 },
    { "ER", 5 },
    { "PP", 6 },
    { "WW", 7 }
}
foreach (var package in mail.Package)
{   // access position
    int index;
    if (!indexPositions.TryGetValue(a.Name, out index)) {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException()
    }
    list[index] = package;
}
```

Comment: Your key and value pairs for the dictionary are mixed up.

Comment: You had the right sort of dictionary with a bug in how it was being built, now you have the wrong sort of dictionary being built okay.

Comment: @JonHanna you're right, I updated it. This is what happens when you try to answer in SO while working - having two things in mind leads to this kind of answers lol

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the usual `OrderBy` `Array.IndexOf` method, the list can also sorted in-place:

```
string[] order = { "KK", "AB", "BC", "DD", "FV", "ER", "PP", "WW" };

list.Sort((a, b) => Array.IndexOf(order, a.Name).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(order, b.Name)));
```

---

A bit more advanced `O(n)`ish alternative:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Name);

list = order.SelectMany(x => lookup[x]).ToList();
```