# Is match statement (structural pattern matching) faster than if-else statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### Disclaimer

I'm currently learning Java and I came across `if-else` and `switch` statement, and I learned [Switch statement is slightly faster than if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767849/8586886).

I'm familiar that Python adds a lot of boilerplate whenever we are creating something (defining functions and stuff) which can be seen by disassembling them using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) function.

#### Question:

Is `match` statement faster than `if-else` in Python? Is it more efficient to use it instead of traditional `if-else` statements?

In case you are unfamiliar with `match` statements, here's the link to [PEP 636 -- Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as far as I know, match/case structures are generally faster than if/elif/else structures. Use them wherever possible over if/elif/else structures. Match/case structures can check if a variable is equal to a value, but they cannot do complex conditions, so you will still be using if/elif/else structures quite a lot (e.g., `if var and not var2:` is only possible with an if/elif/else structure).

Comment: "but they cannot do complex conditions" unfortunately they can

Comment: @timgeb They can? How would you do my example with a match/case structure? It would be very useful to me.

Comment: See [guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id8)

Comment: "As far as I know" - what is the basis for your belief? Is there evidence or a theoretical reason?

Comment: I compared the timing of several `match/case` and `if/else` statements, and in most of them `if/else` was faster if not equal.