# make switch use === comparison not == comparison In PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion

Is there anyway to make it so that the following code still uses a switch and returns `b` not `a`? Thanks!

```
$var = 0;
switch($var) {
    case NULL : return 'a'; break;
    default : return 'b'; break;
}
```

Using if statements, of course, you'd do it like this:

```
$var = 0;
if($var === NULL) return 'a';
else return 'b';
```

But for more complex examples, this becomes verbose.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot use a `===` comparison in a switch statement, since according to the [**switch() documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> Note that switch/case does loose comparison.

This means you'll have to come up with a workaround. From [**the loose comparisons table**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), you could make use of the fact that `NULL == "0"` is false by type casting:

```
<?php
$var = 0;
switch((string)$var) 
{
    case "" : echo 'a'; break; // This tests for NULL or empty string   
    default : echo 'b'; break; // Everything else, including zero
}
// Output: 'b'
?>
```

[**Live Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AQGolL)

Comment: Well, there are other circumstances (not just with NULLs) that I'd like this to work with.

Answer (score 27):

Here is your original code in a "strict" switch statement:

```
switch(true) {
    case $var === null:
        return 'a';
    default:
        return 'b';
}
```

This can also handle more complex switch statement like this:

```
switch(true) {
    case $var === null:
        return 'a';
    case $var === 4:
    case $var === 'foobar':
        return 'b';
    default:
        return 'c';
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, on PHP 8+ you can do it with `match` expression<sup>1</sup>:

```php
echo match (0) {
    NULL=> 'a',
    default => 'b'
};
#~ b
```

The PHP documentation explicitly mentions this difference in comparison to `switch` statement<sup>2</sup>:

> Unlike switch, the comparison is an identity check (`===`) rather than a weak equality check (`==`). Match expressions are available as of PHP 8.0.0. *([from](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php))*

---

<sup>1</sup> See *[match (PHP 8)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)*

<sup>2</sup> See *[switch (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)*

Comment: Neat suggestion!  This is a tough problem to crack; I guess the only drawback with `match()` is that the value must be an expression, i.e. `1=>'a';` or `1=>func();`; but I can't do `1=>print("hello");print("world");`, which a `switch()` would allow.

Answer (score 10):

Not with `switch` - it only does so called "loose" comparisons. You can always replace it with a `if/else if` block, using `===`.

- [Switch documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)
- [Loose comparisons <sup>Docs, too</sup>](https://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

Comment: are you referring to your experience or documentation? If the later, please post a link

Comment: You actually *can* do this with `switch` (see my answer) although I do think that `if-else` is better for this particular job.

Comment: A lot of good answers, sorry I can only pick 1. I went with if/elseif thanks everyone.

Comment: Actually not "always" :) What if not all case blocks have `break` or `return`?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in a switch with string containing numbers ("15.2" is equal to "15.20" in a switch for php)

I solved the problem adding a letter before the text to compare

```
$var = '15.20';
switch ('#'.$var) {
    case '#15.2' :
      echo 'wrong';
    break;
    case '#15.20' :
      echo 'right';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are switching on the variable and expecting integers. Why not simply check the integer status of the variable beforehand using `is_int($val)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

> make switch use === comparison not ==
>   comparison In PHP

Unfortunately [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) uses loose comparison and as far as I know there's no way to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.switch.php):

> Note that switch/case does [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

If you only have two conditions, use an `if` like your second example. Otherwise, check for `NULL` first and switch on the other possibilities:

```
if (is_null($var))
{
  return 'a';
}

switch ($var)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

You can, however, put the `if` statements *inside* the `switch`:

```
switch($var) {
    // Loose cases here

    case 0:
        if($var === NULL) {
            return 'a';
        }

        // Fall through

    default:
        return 'b';
}
```

Or simply:

```
switch($var) {
    // Loose cases here

    default:
        if($var === NULL) {
            return 'a';
        }

        return 'b';
}
```

Comment: At that point why bother with the switch?  You could even do `switch (true) { case $var === null: ... }

Comment: @ircmaxell, I assumed the OP wants fall-through logic or otherwise a reason to use `switch` beyond strict checking at times.

Answer (score 1):

You can also switch on the type of the variable:

```
switch (gettype($var)) {
...
}
```

---

[Per comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525614/make-switch-use-comparison-not-comparison-in-php#comment4234898_3525714) *Peter Ajtai* reminds that `gettype()` may be considered unstable and recommends the `is_*` family of functions:

```php
switch (true) {
    case is_string($var):
       ...
    case is_int($var):
       ...
    case is_numeric($var):
       ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Bad idea - From the docs: `Never use gettype() to test for a certain type, since the returned string may be subject to change in a future version. In addition, it is slow too, as it involves string comparison. Instead, use the is_* functions.`

Comment: If gettype() changes that would make the function useless and the language less reliable. Using is_* doesn't answer the question about the switch. For the rest I agree :)

Comment: _"`is_*` is a perfect case to switch for each `is_*` case."_ - my two cents

Answer (score 1):

Switch statement in php does loose comparisons only (==) see http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Use if/elseif/else if you need strict comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I just use

```
$var === null and $var = -1; // since switch is not type-safe
switch ( $var ) {
    case 0:
        # this tests for zero/empty string/false
        break;
    case -1:
        # this tests for null
        break;
}
```

I think this still looks very readable if the comment starting with `//` is left behind (and the ones starting with `#` are probably best deleted).

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating from your example code, I guess you have a bunch of regular cases and one special case (here, `null`).

The simplest I can figure out is to handle this case before the switch:

```
if ($value === null) {
    return 'null';
}

switch ($value) {
    case 0:
        return 'zero';
    case 1:
        return 'one';
    case 2:
        return 'two';
}
```

Maybe also add a comment to remember `null` would unexpectedly match the `0` case (also the contrary, `0` would match a `null` case).

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way is to check NULL value by using `is_null`

```
function getValue()
{
    $var = 0;   
    switch (true) {
        case is_null($var) : 
            return 'a';
        default : 
            return 'b';
    }
}

echo getValue();
```

Comment: The best, however, is `=== null` since it avoids the unnecessary function call overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Create an assertion-like class and put whatever logic you want in it; so long as "true" methods return `$this` (and nothing else to avoid false-positives.)

```
class Haystack
{
    public $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function isExactly($n)
    {
        if ($n === $this->value)
            return $this;
    }
}

$var = new Haystack(null);

switch ($var) {
    case $var->isExactly(''):
        echo "the value is an empty string";
        break;

    case $var->isExactly(null):
        echo "the value is null";
        break;
}
```

Or you can put your switch inside the actual class:

```
class Checker
{
    public $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function isExactly($n)
    {
        if ($n === $this->value)
            return $this;
    }

    public function contains($n)
    {
        if (strpos($this->value, $n) !== false)
            return $this;
    }

    public static function check($str)
    {
        $var = new self($str);

        switch ($var) {
            case $var->isExactly(''):
                return "'$str' is an empty string";
            case $var->isExactly(null):
                return "the value is null";
            case $var->contains('hello'):
                return "'$str' contains hello";
            default:
                return "'$str' did not meet any of your requirements.";
        }
    }
}

var_dump(Checker::check('hello world'));   # string(28) "'hello world' contains hello"
```

Of course that that point you might want to re-evaluate what you want to do with what you're checking and use a real validation library instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test both **value** and **type** of your variable, then build a new **string variable** containing both informations and compare it with your different scenarios (by concatenation) it should work for your case if you implement all possible types (according to [gettype() documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.gettype.php)), example :

```
<?php
    $var= 9999;
    $valueAndTypeOfVar = (string)$var.' '.gettype($var);
    switch($valueAndTypeOfVar) {
        case "$var boolean" : echo 'a'; break;
        case "$var integer" : echo 'b'; break; 
        case "$var double" : echo 'c'; break;
        case "$var string" : echo 'd'; break; 
        case "$var array" : echo 'e'; break;
        case "$var object" : echo 'f'; break; 
        case "$var resource" : echo 'g'; break;
        case "$var NULL" : echo 'h'; break; 
        case "$var unknown type" : echo 'i'; break; 
        default: echo 'j'; break;
    }

   // Outputs: 'b'
?>
```