# How to handle a PHP switch with different types?

Tags: php

How can I make the switch respect data types ( is there a workaround better then if/else ) ?

$value = false; // should echo false

$value = null; // should echo null

```
switch ($value) {
    case '0' :
        echo 'zero';
        break;
    case '' :
        echo 'empty';
        break;
    case null :
        echo 'null';
        break;
    case false :
        echo 'false';
        break;
    default :
        echo 'default';
        break;
}
```

## Conclusion

Switch/case does loose comparison.

Solutions: switch with ifs or if/else

Comment: By "not working" I mean: to respect or take somehow into account the value type

Comment: let's try that again, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Oh come on, let's not go into semantics. If it's boolean false it should echo false.

Comment: You need to be explicit. In this case, the script is "working", it just doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @Hamish, We [don't want loose comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3525614/632951). 'Nuff said, clear as water.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
switch (true) {
    case $value === '0' :
        echo 'zero';
        break;
    case $value === '' :
        echo 'empty';
        break;
    case $value === null :
        echo 'null';
        break;
    case $value === false :
        echo 'false';
        break;
    default :
        echo 'default';
        break;
}
```

I think, it's more readable than a `if-elseif`-chain like given below:

```
if ($value === '0') {
  echo 'zero';
} else if ($value === '') {
  echo 'empty';
} else if ($value === null) {
  echo 'null';
} else if ($value === false) {
  echo 'false';
} else {
  echo 'default';
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't agree on the readability part (one extra level of indention, same number of lines (if you format the if/else nicer than @nicola did) and a more direct way of expressing what you do to the next why that reads that (wtf factor @switch(true) for a second).  But I'm nitpicking. +1

Comment: hey crunch, what a good hack huh, good thinking, enlightened me about how 'switch' actually operates

Comment: yeah, but i'm with edorian, don't like one extra indentation, it's up to danip to choose which to use

Comment: @edorian: Hmm... I replaced the "far more readable" with "I think, its more readable" ;) But I still think, its cleaner for more than (lets say) 3 oder 4 cases. With `switch(true)` every case statement is evaluated into something like `true == ($statement)`. I thought, it was obvious.

Comment: and more, i hate using 'switch' because if we miss a 'break;' then everything crashes

Comment: @nicola: So dont miss it :p That you can omit the `break` is a feature, that you cannot rebuild with `if-else` that easy. On the other hand, if you suspect, that you will miss a `break` and dont realize it, until all crashes, than you probably didnt test your application.

Comment: OK, I sent my last comment to fast. It is easy to rebuild, if you chain the expressions into one `if`-statement with `||` ;) However, is even less readable. To point that out: I really dont care, which of those others use ;) Both behave equal without any weird hacks, so I will not going to say "Hey, thats ugly!"

Comment: @King fair point, Also thanks for including the comparison. I guess i can see it for this example now :)

Comment: @KingCrunch, You can combine `else if` into one word: `elseif`

Comment: @Pacerier I follow PSR2-standards. PSR2 discourages `elseif` in favor of `else if`. Anyway, I prefer `else if` regardless of PSR2, because it makes ugly `if-elseif`-chains like the one above more obvious. Of course you can disagree. It's just, that `else if` in my answer was written like that by intention :)

Comment: `switch(true)` is a desperately bad construct

Comment: @DevDonkey I don't think discussions about preferences belongs in here. I'd still always recommend to at least think about "breaking the rules" to increase readability. After that you can still disagree :)

Comment: @DevDonkey why is it a bad construct?

Answer (score 5):

i believe you can try if-then to facilitate the use of '===' instead:

```
<?php
$value = 0;

if ($value==="") {
  echo "blank (string)";
}
else
if ($value==="0") {
  echo "zero (string)";
}
else
if ($value===false) {
  echo "false (boolean)";
}
else
if ($value===null) {
  echo "null (object)";
}
else
if ($value===0) {
  echo "zero (number)";
}
else {
  echo "other";
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, several years old answer :) But anyway: When I read the left most column -- thats how I track down code the fast way -- I see several `if`s. It's pretty easy to miss the `else`, that makes the `if` to an `elseif`, and therefore I see several independent conditions at first, instead of a chain. I wouldn't recommened this notation.

Answer (score 3):

in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) manual it is a

> note: Note that switch/case does [loose comparision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

```
"loose comparison" means that switch won't check the type. 
 switch will only compare values:
```

---

```
<?php 
if('a string' == 0) echo 'a string is 0' . PHP_EOL;
if('a string' === 0) echo 'but you will never see this' . PHP_EOL;
switch(0){
    case 'a string': echo 'a string' . PHP_EOL;
    case 'another string': echo 'another string' . PHP_EOL;
}

if('a string' == true) echo 'a string is TRUE' . PHP_EOL;
if('a string' === true) echo 'but you will never see this' . PHP_EOL;
switch(true){
    case 'a string': echo 'a string' . PHP_EOL;
    case 'another string': echo 'another string' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>

will output:
a string is 0
a string
another string
a string is TRUE
a string
another string
```

Answer (score 1):

another option, depending on what you like to look at:

```
switch($foo ?: strtoupper(gettype($foo))){
    case 'bar':
    case 'bork':
        echo $foo;
        break;

    case 'NULL': // $foo === null
        echo 'null';
        break;

    case 'INTEGER': // $foo === 0
        echo 'zero';
        break;

    case 'ARRAY': // $foo === array()
        echo 'array';
        break;

    case 'STRING': // $foo === ''
        echo 'empty';
        break;

    case 'BOOLEAN': // $foo === false
        echo 'false';
        break;

    default:
        echo $foo;
        break;
}
```

depending on your data, you could include an underscore for added clarity, like '_NULL', but it's not as clean IMO.

personally, I concur with the accepted answer for something like a quick null check:

```
case $foo === null:
```

Comment: I really like your solution. Can you elaborate on the `$foo ?: strtoupper(gettype($foo))` part – specifically that `?:` operator? I'm thinking just `strtoupper(gettype($foo))` should be enough, but that's only because I don't know what the `?:` operator does. … +1 for not putting `true` in the switch-statement (and actually switching on the data type)! :D

Comment: ?: is the Ternary operator in PHP. It's a shorthand if/then statement. like `$x = (($a > $b) ? $a : $b);` PHP let's you omit the "true" condition like: `$x = $a ?: $b;` so it checks if $a evaluates to true, if so, choose $a otherwise choose $b. so in the above switch, it uses the value of $foo unless it is false. and then the below are the "false" data types it evaluates to. (I would not code this professionally. if you're at this point, something should probably be simplified farther up stream to avoid bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that you're asking PHP to [juggle types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

If you see the [PHP type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) you'll see that, for example, `null` and `''` are loosly equivalent, ie `null == ''`.

Comment: Yes, he's asking **how** to ask PHP **not** to juggle types.