# problem on switch case

Tags: php, regex, switch-statement

how can fix it or add regexp ?

```
case substr($rrr['url'],-4)=='.jpg' || '.png' || '.gif' || '.tif' || '.tiff':
```

Comment: Is the check case sensitive? `http://example.com/icon.JPG` What about query parameters? `http://example.com/icon.jpg?src=search` What about other pages? `http://example.com/evil#justlookslegit.jpg`

Comment: Try `strrchr($rrr["url"], ".")` to get the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
case in_array(substr($rrr['url'],-4), array('.jpg','.png','.gif','.tif')):
case in_array(substr($rrr['url'],-5), array('.tiff')):
```

Note, that I omit `break;` between the `case`-expression.

Also cool:

```
case in_array(pathinfo($rrr['url'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), array('jpg','png','gif','tif', 'tiff')):
```

The snippet from the question doesnt work, because its evaluated into (shortened)

```
(substr($rrr['url'],-4)=='.jpg') || '.png'
```

This works, but oviously it doesnt make much sense and is very probably not, what is expected.

Update: This solution seems much cleaner. It assumes, that `$rrr['url']` is the only interesting here. See comments

```
switch (pathinfo($rrr['url'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)):
  case 'jpg':
  case 'png':
  case 'gif':
  case 'tif':
  case 'tiff':
    do_something();
  break;
}
```

Comment: If this is indeed used as a `switch` `case`, this will not work like you expect it to work. If it works at all, it's just because the result of that expression happens to loosely compare to the `switch` comparison value.

Comment: @deceze: The questioner omitted the `switch($expr)`-part, so I had to guess. Maybe its just `switch(true)`.

Comment: @King Sure, but that would be just as weird and needs pointing out.

Comment: @deceze: Hmm.. valid point. Maybe I guessed a little bit too much. But what is weird with `switch(true)`?

Comment: @King IMO `switch(true)` is abusing the `switch` statement and would be better replaced with an `if`. Maybe that's just me though.

Comment: @deceze: I already had such a discussion here today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563079/how-to-handle-a-php-switch-with-different-types/5563199#5563199 See the comments :) I dont see, that this is some kind of abusing and in my oppinion its more readable with many similar expressions, so I prefer the readability against the dogma :)

Comment: @King Hehe, must be `switch`-Wednesday today. ;-) Looking at the OP's code I kinda don't expect him to be using `true` as the `switch` expression though...

Comment: @deceze: Just realized: With `pathinfo()` a much cleaner solution (in I think our both oppinions ;)) is possible. See update in answer. This way it feels exactly, what `switch` is designed for.

Comment: I'm impressed you interpreted the gibberish of that question well enough to give a good answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

1. `$foo == A || B || C` doesn't work, this needs to be `$foo == A || $foo == B || $foo == C` or `in_array($foo, array(A, B, C))`.
2. You can't have complex `case`s within `switch` statements. Each case can only have one value against which the comparison value will be compared. You'd have to write this as separate fall-through `case`s:

   ```
   switch ($foo) {
       case A :
       case B :
       case C :
           bar();
           break;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `A == B || C || D` statement for that, only `A == B || A == C || A == D`

Also, urls can have GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) of dot, get substring after rightest dot position (which returned by strrpos), define array of allowed extensions (it also makes your code reusable), and then use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like this:

```
$rpos = strrpos($rrr['url'], '.');
$ext = substr($rrr['url'], $rpos+1);
$allowedExtensions = array('jpg','png', 'gif', 'tif', 'tiff');
///....
if (in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)) {
///....
```