# PHP Identical operator (===) switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make switch use === comparison not == comparison In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525614/make-switch-use-comparison-not-comparison-in-php)

I'm attempting a:

`switch (1){
case(): ....
}`

It seams as though `1` and `1.0` both satisfy this switch condition. I've tried `switch ('1')` to no avail as well. Can I make the switch statement choose `1` and  not `1.0`?

Thanks