# Switch statement and NULL versus 0

Tags: php

```
switch ($i) {
    case NULL:
        echo "It is NULL";
        break;
    case 0:
        echo "It is zero";
        break;
}
```

If I set $i to NULl or 0, the switch statement is evaluating it to NULL. Is switch not ready to handle the equivalent of this:

```
if ($i === NULL) {
    echo 'This is NULL';
}
if ($i == 0) {
    echo 'This is Zero';
}
```

if so, should I assume I have to have an IF loop instead of SWITCH?

Comment: This is related and should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525614/make-switch-use-comparison-not-comparison-in-php

Comment: switch does an equivalence test (==) not an equality test (===)

Comment: switch doesn't do identity checks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also going to suggest casting your switch input variable as something you can expect like (int) or (string) to make sure you're validating the cases properly.