# PHP Switch Condition Catching Unmatched Condition

Tags: php, switch-statement

I encountered a problem today, (which I managed to solve). However, I don't understand why it is this way.

I have a switch condition like this:

```
switch( $message['approval_status'] ){
    case self::APPROVED:
       $state['approved'] = true;
       break;
    // other irrelevant conditions
    default:
       break;
}
```

Where

```
const APPROVED = 2
```

I passed in 2 variables,

If I were to use this function twice, once with

`$message['approval_status'] = 1` and another one with

`$message['approval_status'] = true`

The above switch statement passes the integer as expected, which is to go to the default condition. However, the variable with has `$message['approval_status'] = true` is caught by `case self::APPROVED:` even though `self::APPROVED = 2`

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compare the two, PHP has to convert "2" to a boolean (switch statements uses loose comparison, so values of different types must be cast to a single type).  Anything that is non-zero is converted to "true."

Comment: so, there's no such thing as a `===` switch?

Comment: That's correct  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525614/make-switch-use-comparison-not-comparison-in-php

Comment: why does it convert to bool though? It's a int vs bool test, shouldn't it convert bool to int?

Comment: This has to do with "type juggling."  When loosely comparing two values of different types, PHP has a set of rules that are defined based on context.  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php.

If we reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting, it says: "a value will be automatically converted [to a boolean] if an operator, function or control structure requires a boolean argument."  Since switch() requires a boolean result, it converts both to boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is evaluating a boolean (true) against a non-zero value (also true). The test is done on true/false, so it passes.