# If or Switch for getting parameter PHP

Tags: php

I have a lot of `php` file.

To access each `php` I am using parameter.

Example : `index.php?route=changepassword`, `index.php?route=aboutus`, etc

I have a `route.php` to link the parameter to the correct file

Its better to use

`If-Else statement`

```
$route = $_GET['route'];
if ($route==changepassword) {
   //statement
} else if ($route==aboutus) {
   //statement
}
```

of using `switch-case` ?

```
$route = $_GET['route'];
switch ($route) {
case "changepassword" :
   //statement
   break;
case "aboutus" :
   //statement
   break;
}
```

This is just 2 file, I have 10+ file, it is better to use what?

Comment: There is no better. There is only Zuul.

Comment: Switches IMO. Easier to read, write, and maintain.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["if" versus "switch"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399755/if-versus-switch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an array-map wherever you can:

```
$map = array(
    "changepassword" => "includes/changepw.php",
    "aboutus" => "templ/aboutus.php",
);
```

In that simple case (you didn't elaborate on your `//statements`) you can just utilize them as:

```
incude( $map[$_GET["route"]] );
```

As commonly you can map them onto classes or callbacks, or anonymous functions.

But lastly a map is more concise and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of conditions, go for code clarity before performance, if there's any performance to be gained with either solution.

I would definitely go with `switch-case`.

See this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399755/if-versus-switch) with similar answers.