# Difference between if and case

Tags: php, if-statement

I am teaching myself PHP and have a question about IF and CASE. They seem quite similar to me, and was wondering if somebody could explain the main difference, or why/when I would use one over the other.

The example I am looking at it fairly basic - see below;

#### IF

```
if ($i == 1 ||
    $i == 2 ||
    $i == 3) {
 echo '$i is somewhere between 1 and 3.';
}
```

#### CASE

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    echo '$i is somewhere between 1 and 3.';
    break;
```

I am new to php and appreciate any advice.

Comment: imagine you have 100 cases. which one will you choose?

Comment: Or even: `if ( in_array($i, array(1,2,3)) ) {}`

Comment: `case` comes with `switch`.

Comment: @Raptor I'd use a visitor pattern for 100 cases :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From logical point of view there is not much difference, both of them are conditional branching block.

Beside that, `switch statement` executes faster, as it knows all the branching where the jump has to made, while for the `if` statement the same is not true.

consider reading . . .

1. ["if" versus "switch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399755/if-versus-switch)
2. [Is "else if" faster than "switch() case"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case)
3. [If-else vs switch – Which is better?](http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2009/08/if-else-vs-switch-%E2%80%93-which-is-better/)