# If block vs Switch-Case block

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Generally is there a performance difference between using an if block with many else ifs compared to a switch case block? Do some languages or style conventions prefer one over the other?

Specifically I am curious about Matlab, C,  and C++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/switch-vs-if-else

Comment: Maybe I also should ask this kind of question, to get some rep? Who cares about duplicates...

Comment: @BkaXpirit, this was no the intent at all. If you really care to know I asked this question quick on my mobile device so I didn't much time to browse through other questions. Nothing popped up when I entered the title when I first asked the question. Besides as of this comment, I don't think 17 rep is doing me that much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A switch can be optimized by the compiler, in some cases, into a lookup table and branch. This could be considerably faster than multiple if/else-ifs.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the optimizer can turn a switch into a calculated jmp, so it can be faster.  This is possible because you always switch on an integer constant.