# The best way for loads of IF - ELSE - INCLUDE?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if ($page == null || $page == "home")
        require_once ("home.php");
    else if ($page == "bill")
        require_once ("bill.php");
    else if ($page == "product")
        require_once ("product.php");
    else if ($page == "addproduct")
        require_once ("addproduct.php");
    else if ($page == "editpd")
        require_once ("editpd.php");

    /** ... MANY LINES ... **/

    else if ($page == "permission")
        require_once ("permission.php");
    else if ($page == "options")
        require_once ("option.php");
    else // NOT FOUND, REDIRECT HOME
        echo "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
?>
```

The above code is loads of `IF ELSE and REQUIRE_ONCE`.

I have started worrying about the execution time when the system is developed, it means that i have to write `IF ELSE and REQUIRE_ONCE` more and more.

So i really want to know,

What is a solution or the better way for this in case not use any framework?

Comment: why not to use `switch` statement

Comment: @MMK: Is `switch` statement really faster than `IF ELSE` in this case?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10773060/3935280

Comment: a better approach is: create an array with all the names of the pages.
@Barmar's answer is really cool. You should get rid of all the `if else`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like all the include files have the same name as `$page`, so you can use string processing to remove all the duplicate code.

```
$pages = array('home', 'bill', 'product', ...);
$page = $page == null ? 'home' : $page;
if (in_array($page, $pages)) {
    require_once ($page . ".php");
}
```

Comment: The "in_array()" is very important in this solution, as it limits the allowed pages to load.

Otherwise you'll get a security flaw, where a user can require_once any php on your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$page = preg_replace('/\W+/', '', $page); 
if (is_file($page . '.php')) {
    require_once $page . '.php';
}
```

or with whitelist

```
$whitelist = ['permission', '....'];
if (in_array($page, $whitelist)) {
    require_once $page . '.php';
}
```

or for more performance

```
$whitelist = ['permission' => true, '...' => true];
if (isset($whitelist[$page])) {
    require_once $page . '.php';
}
```

Comment: btw: require_once isn't a function, it's a statement, like echo... so no ( and ) are needed.... you shouldn't use them

Comment: Don't use a solution like this without a whitelist!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `switch()` statement, like so:

```
<?php
    switch($page) {
        case "home":
        case null:
            require_once ("home.php");
            break;
        case "bill":
            require_once ("bill.php");
            break;
        case "product":
            require_once ("product.php");
            break;
        case "addproduct":
            require_once ("addproduct.php");
            break;
        case "editpd":
            require_once ("editpd.php");
            break;

    /** ... MANY LINES ... **/


        case "permission":
            require_once ("permission.php");
            break;
        case "options":
            require_once ("option.php");
            break;
        default:
            echo "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
            break:
    }
?>
```

If however the structure stays the same, maybe this would be a better option:

```
if(is_null($page)) {
    $page = 'home';
}
if(file_exists($page . '.php')) {
    require_once($page . '.php');
} else {
    echo "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
}
```

Comment: never ever do this second version please..... require_once understands ../ pathes and you could end $page with null-bytes to include whatever you want

Comment: @MichaelFreund Please interpret the full code instead of one line of it... This can never happen since the `file_exists()` function would not find `../.php` a valid filename...

Comment: `file_exists('../../../badfile' . '.php')` is absolutely valid, if it exists.... its a bad file_inclusion leak, http://hakipedia.com/index.php/File_Inclusion#wrong_defense_3:_adding_content_to_filename

Comment: @MichaelFreund If you have security concerns, please follow the following procedure; 1. lookup function reference on PHP and read the big red outlined part (http://php.net/file_exists). 2. who said `$page` is something a user can alter? It is not specified a whitelist is needed, and this cannot be deduced from the question asked

Answer (score 0):

```
if($page == NULL) {
    include 'home.php';
} else {
    include "$page.php";
}
```