# Performance topic: If with multiple || or switch case?

Tags: php, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a small script to format the prices depending on the origin of the user.
My question now is what is better performance wise?

```
function FormatPrice($Price) {
        $Locale = $this->Locale;
        switch ($Locale) {
        case "en-GB":
        case "en-IE":
        case "he-IL":
        case "mt-MT":
        case "zh-CN":
            return number_format($Price, 2, '.', ',');
        default:
            return number_format($Price, 2, ',', '.');

        }
    }
```

or

```
function FormatPrice($Price) {
        $Locale = $this->Locale;
        if ($Locale === "en-GB" || $Locale === "en-IE" || $Locale === "he-IL" || $Locale === "mt-MT" || $Locale === "zh-CN") {
            return number_format($Price, 2, '.', ',');
        } else {
            return number_format($Price, 2, ',', '.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it seems there is no need for all the conditions to be checked. Just reverse the conditions. Check for `$Locale === "zh-CN"`

Comment: Both `switch` case and `if`  condition doesn't make any difference at all but if you multiple or condition then you can use `switch` as its better in readable ways and for more you can get an answer over [which-is-faster-and-better-switch-case-or-if-else-if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773047/which-is-faster-and-better-switch-case-or-if-else-if) post

Answer (score 1):

Use the below link to understand more
It seems that the compiler is better in optimizing a switch-statement than an if-statement.
[Case vs If Else If: Which is more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158759/case-vs-if-else-if-which-is-more-efficient)