# Codeigniter : Using switch with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I am passing array data to my view  like this

```
public function login(){
       $array= array(
           array(
                'type'           =>     'text',
                'usrname'        =>     'username',
                'class'          =>     'form-control',
                'placeholder'    =>     'Username',
             ),
           array(
                'type'           =>     'password',
                'class'          =>     'form-control',
                'placeholder'    =>     'Password',
            ),
           array(
                'type'          =>'heading',
                'heading'       =>'Not a Memer YET ?',
            ),

       );

    $output['data']=$array;
    $this->load->view('authentication',$output);
```

in my view this is what i'm doing

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key=> $value):?>
        <?php 
            switch ($value){
                case  $value['type']=='heading':
                    echo $value['heading'];
                    break;
                case  $value['type']=='text':
                    echo 'textfield';
                    break;
             }

        ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

this is working properly but i just want to ask is it standard practice the way i am doing it or there can be any better way to traverse this array in switch  .

Need your help please

This question is not about if i should use switch or if else , i want to know the way I've used switch in terms of coding is it correct or not ?or i can improve it .

Comment: use `if` as alternative

Comment: You might want to read up on PHP MVC Architecture. Also your current solution will sooner or later get pretty messy with more elements and more data in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is Faster and better, Switch Case or if else if?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773047/which-is-faster-and-better-switch-case-or-if-else-if)

Comment: @MioBambino i gave it a try and requested to point out how can i improve it , if ts messy gve me bit of hint to sort out

Comment: @Spartan so if  i use if else that would be good for this scenario instead of switch ?

Comment: There are no diff. You can use either `switch` or either `if`

Comment: Is it standard practice the way i've used it in  my example ? please correct  me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing in switch case, you can modify your switch code something like this.

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key=> $value):?>
<?php 
    switch ($value['type']){
        case 'heading':
                        echo "heading";
                        break;
        case 'text':
                        echo 'textfield';
                        break;
        default : //default code here
     }

?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```