# A way to summarize many commands like if... and if... do

Tags: php, command, summarize

I've created a question and answer page to determine the level of interest of each user for different products
like this:
how much u like x (betwin 1-10)
These questions are more than 30, and if I want to write a single command line for each possibilities, it's almost impossible.
the commands do like this:

```
if $a <=5 and $b <=6 and $c <=7 and... do ...
if $a<= 8 and $b <=7 and $c >= 5 and $d <=8 do...
```

I want the commands to work this way
Is there a better way to do this?
thanks

Comment: You could use a `switch()` statement.

Comment: [Which is Faster and better, Switch Case or if else if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773047/which-is-faster-and-better-switch-case-or-if-else-if)

Comment: What do $a, $b etc. represent - are they answers to different questions?

Comment: the question is unclear for me, what $a, $b, $c are? . Could you make an example with 2 or 3 questions ?

Comment: i've add another command. $a $b $c is a number betwin 1-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use a `switch` statement. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

**Example code:**

```
$i = 10;

switch($i):
    case ($i <= 0): // or for example: case (0)
        return 'It\'s 0 or lower than 0';
        break;
    case ($i > 0 && $i < 10):
        return 'Number is between 0 and 10';
        break;
    case ($i >= 10):
        return 'Number is 10 or higher';
        break;
    default:
        return false;
endswitch;
// You can use echo instead of return, but i prefer to use these statements in a function instead of the html page.
```

More information about the differences between `if` and `switch` is provided by Masivuye Cokile as a comment in your question: [Which is Faster and better, Switch Case or if else if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773047/which-is-faster-and-better-switch-case-or-if-else-if)

I hope this helped. Let me know.

Comment: thanks this is good way.Is there another good ways like use function or class?

Comment: Yea, some many used functions can be found here: http://vegibit.com/most-useful-php-array-functions/