# Is switch just as bad as if?

Tags: performance, optimization, language-agnostic, compiler-optimization, branch-prediction

I read on StackOverflow that using

```
if(someCondition)
{
    someCode();
}
else
{
    alternateCode();
}
```

can be inefficient due to susceptibility to branch misprediction (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/is-if-expensive) for example).

So is a `switch`-construct, e.g.,

```
switch (someCondition)
{
    case (someCase):
        something();
        break;
    case (otherCase):
        someOtherInstructions();
        break;
    default:
        defaultAction();
        break;
}
```

any different in this respect (besides the fact that I have allowed for three possibilities)?

Comment: That's a very rare definition of 'expensive'! It's sort of like saying that $0.0001 is expensive.

Comment: @Gabe: as always, that depends on the application. IF you need to spend $0.0001 several billion times, it does start to matter (although I agree it hardly ever is the majority of the cost).

Comment: I prefer case statements because they're easier to read and reduces the chance of logic errors on the part of the programmer. No idea whether there's a difference in efficiency of the actual execution.

Comment: Related (perhaps Java specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i

Comment: Related (perhaps C++ specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement

Comment: Related (perhaps C# specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`if` statements aren't "expensive", conditional branches may be.**  The issue isn't which of the many different high-level statements you choose to write - `if`, `switch`, `for`, `while`, *etc*.  The issue is that modern computers work very well executing an unconditional instruction path, but when there's a decision point, they may slow down.  Since you can't do anything interesting in computing without decision points (*i.e.*, conditional branches), you might as well ignore the choice of high-level language construct.

Comment: Switch statements don't necessarily compile to conditional branches though (think jump tables).

Comment: I guess the main point here is, don't worry about it unless you are running a piece of code thousands (or millions) of times...

Comment: @sepp2k Agreed.  But that's a compiler decision and it can depend on the specific values involved.  Regardless, the point isn't "if vs. switch", it's "conditional branch prediction".

Comment: long answer => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/is-if-expensive