# Simple Computing Machine

Tags: java, bluej

I'm working on a Von Neumann Machine, I'm writing a java program that works like a simple machine, that follows instructions. It reads a textfile and depending on the OpCode in the file, it either stores, adds, substract, multilply, divide and load numbers. Should I use a switch statement or alot of if else statements?

- 01 07 // load 7 to Accumulator
- 21 91 // store Accumulator M1
- 05 13 // add 13 to 7 and keep 20 in the Acc.
- 99 99 // print Acc. contents
- 06 12 // subtract 12 from Acc.
- 21 91 // store 8 to M1

  ```
  public class Machine{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  ```

  {

  ```
    File file = new File("U:/op.txt");
    Scanner readfile = new Scanner(file);

      while(readfile.hasNextInt()){
        String read = readfile.nextLine();

        System.out.println(read);
      }


  }
  ```

Comment: I think it's very opinion based. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed , a switch is usually more efficient.

Comment: How to I get the second number in the file and instead of the first one (01 7) I want to store 7 to a variable called Acc instead of 01? @S.Klumpers `switch(read)
        {
            case 01:
            Acc = M1 + read;
            System.out.println(Acc);
            break;
            case 21:
            
            break;
            case 05:
            
            case 99:
            
            case 06:
             }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Machine{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("U:/op.txt");
        Scanner readfile = new Scanner(file);

        int acc = 0;
        int M1 = 0;

        while(readfile.hasNextInt())
        {
            String read = readfile.nextLine();

            switch(read.substring(0, 2))
            {
                case "01":
                    acc = M1 + Integer.parseInt(read.substring(3, 5));
                    System.out.println(acc);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `read.substring(0, 2)` gets the first two characters.
The `read.substring(3, 5)` gets the other two and `Integer.parseInt(intString)` gets the integer value of these two characters.

This can be reused for all your examples by adding in the other cases in the switch.

Comment: I tried that before it kept giving me "incompatible types - found java.lang.String but expexted int" @S.Klumpers

Comment: Can you determine at which line the error occurs or attach the full code?

Comment: `File file = new File("U:/op.txt");
      Scanner readfile = new Scanner(file);
        
        while(readfile.hasNextLine()){
        String read = readfile.nextLine();
         
            switch(read.substring(0,2))
            {
             case "01":
             acc = m1 + Integer.parseInt(read.substring(3, 5));
             System.out.println(acc);
             break;
             
             case "21": 
             acc = m1;
             break;
             
             case "05":
             acc = m1 + Integer.parseInt(read.substring(3, 5));
             break;
            }`

Comment: how do i post the code correctly i used ``and it doesn't post correctly. Anyways it gives an error at the switch statement. I put the switch statement in the while loop.

Comment: I edited it until it compiled for me, I can't run it though, it gives me some sort of exception about not being able to find the file.