# Switch vs If-Else Performance

Tags: performance, powershell, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following `If` block which in a logon script which I am re-writing:

```
If ($distinguishedname -match 'Joe Bloggs') {
    Map-Drive 'X' "\\path\to\drive"
}
If ($distinguishedname -match 'Steve Bloggs') {
    Map-Drive 'X' "\\path\to\drive"
}
If ($distinguishedname -match 'Joe Jobs') {
    Map-Drive 'X' "\\path\to\drive"
}
```

Which obviously needs to be re-written as an `If/Else` statement (as each user only has 1 name!) However, I prefer the look of the following `switch -Regex` method:

```
switch -Regex ($distinguishedname) {
    'Joe Bloggs' {Map-Drive 'X' "\\path\to\drive"; break}
    'Steve Bloggs' {Map-Drive 'X' "\\path\to\drive"; break}
    'Joe Jobs' {Map-Drive 'X' "\\path\to\drive"; break}
}
```

My question is - would using a switch in this manner have any impact on the performance of this function? It must be better than the above (`if/if/if`), as not every possibility is evaluated each time, but would the `switch` be faster than an `ifelse/ifelse/else`?

Comment: You may want to use groups instead of testing users one by one but that my not apply to your situation

Comment: @sodawillow Thanks for your comment - I am testing groups elsewhere in the script, but the setup which is being performed here is unique for those users so this seems like the best way in my case

Comment: [Related if not a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote this test to check if I could figure out which way is better using `Measure-Command`:

```
function switchtest {
    param($name)

    switch -Regex ($name) {
        $optionsarray[0] {
            Write-host $name
            break
        }
        $optionsarray[1] {
            Write-host $name
            break
        }
        $optionsarray[2] {
            Write-host $name
            break
        }
        $optionsarray[3] {
            Write-host $name
            break
        }
        $optionsarray[4] {
            Write-host $name
            break
        }
        default { }
    }
}
function iftest {
    param($name)

    If ($name -match $optionsarray[0]) {Write-host $name}
    ElseIf ($name -match $optionsarray[1]) {Write-host $name}
    ElseIf($name -match $optionsarray[2]) {Write-host $name}
    ElseIf($name -match $optionsarray[3]) {Write-host $name}
    ElseIf($name -match $optionsarray[4]) {Write-host $name}
}

$optionsarray = @('Joe Bloggs', 'Blog Joggs', 'Steve Bloggs', 'Joe Jobs', 'Steve Joggs')
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) {
    $iftime = 0
    $switchtime = 0

    $rand = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 4
    $name = $optionsarray[$rand]

    $iftime = (Measure-Command {iftest $name}).Ticks
    $switchtime = (Measure-Command {switchtest $name}).Ticks

    Add-Content -Path C:\path\to\outfile\timetest.txt -Value "$switchtime`t$iftime"
}
```

**Results**

On average, this is how each function performed in 10,000 tests:

> Switch - 11592.8566
>
> IfElse - 15740.3281

The results were not the most consistent (sometimes `switch` was faster, sometimes `ifelse` was faster) but as `switch` is faster overall (on mean average) I will be using this instead of `ifelse`.

Would appreciate any feedback on this decision and my testing.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, switch statements work by building a jump table in the assembly code and using that to determine the appropriate route instead of using comparators like if/else.  That's why switch statements are faster.  I believe that with strings, the compiler generates a hash code of the strings and uses that to implement the jump table so that the switch statement is still faster.  So the switch statement **should** be faster than the if/if/if you have written above but it may not be since switch statements typically rely on the options being somewhat evenly spaced (e.g. 1 2 3 or 5 10 15).

With that being said, why don't you use an if/else-if/else-if instead of an if/if/if?  That'll definitely be faster since not every option is evaluated each time.

Comment: You sure this would apply equally to a dynamic/interpreted language like PowerShell? How would you even implement a hash-based jump table for a switch that supports regex pattern matching?

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your answer. I decided to opt for the `switch` based on some testing (See my own answer). Do you think those tests are a valid way of determining which statement is faster?