# Better: switch-case or if-else?

Tags: java, switch-statement, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If/Else vs. Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/if-else-vs-switch)

I have two codes here, i just wanted to ask which of the two is better in terms of writability(ease of writing the codes) and in terms of readability (ease of understanding the codes).

**switch-case:**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Quarter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int day;
        String input="";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Input a number from 1 to 3: ");

        try{
            input=in.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        day=Integer.parseInt(input);

        switch(day){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                System.out.println("1st Quarter");
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                System.out.println("2nd Quarter");
                break;
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            System.out.println("3rd Quarter");
            break;
            case 10:
            case 11:
            case 12:
                System.out.println("4th Quarter");
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Error!");
        }

    }
}
```

**if-else:**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Days{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int day;
        String input="";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Input a number from 1 to 12: ");

        try{
            input=in.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        day=Integer.parseInt(input);

        if(day>=1 && day<=3){
            System.out.println("1st Quarter");
        }else
        if(day>=4 && day<=6){
            System.out.println("2nd Quarter");
        }else
        if(day>=7 && day<=9){
            System.out.println("3rd Quarter");
        }else
        if(day>=10 && day<=12){
            System.out.println("4th Quarter");
        }else
            System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite a duplicate as that is for c# and this is java so java searchers would not find the original

Comment: I've noticed quite a few questions asking the same thing, but for a different language. Maybe someone should make a community wiki question, and have an answer which covers the question for each language?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Neither, I'd do this one:

```
String[] out = {
    "1st Quarter",
    "2nd Quarter",
    "3rd Quarter",
    "4th Quarter"
};

if (1 <= day && day <= 12) {
    System.out.println(out[(day - 1) / 3]);
} else {
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

Comment: I agree, doing this is much cleaner than using `if` or `switch` blocks.

Comment: There are 12 months to put into 4 bins, so we should be dividing by 3.

Comment: I support this answer, however to make it better:  System.out.println((day>0 && day<13) ? out[(day-1)/3] : "Error!" ) ;

Comment: Your code is great, but I can't +1 it on account of the fact that you didn't answer the switch/case vs. if/else question, which could have been merely theoretical in nature.  This answer unfortunately isn't going to help him next time he faces a switch/case or if/else situation where doing something like this is not possible.

Comment: @Michael: the next time he get into this situation, he'd have three choices: switch/case, if/else, or dictionary/array indexing. The switch/case or if/else situation is a false dichotomy.

Comment: Very easy to do in this case as all you are doing is outputting a string contained in the `out` array, but I don't see how this could be used if you were doing something like executing different chunks of code depending on what key(s) the user pressed, e.g. Escape->if (selection.length) {selection.clear();} else {textbox.clear}, Enter-> submission code, Ctrl+b->toggle bold, etc.

Comment: @Michael: You can use a Dictionary/Hashtable/Map to map between the keys to function objects. However, given that Java's syntax for creating function objects are really clunky, if there is no requirement for being able to remap the key binding, I'd probably use a switch-case.

Comment: Alright... +1 then for the more abstract answer!

Comment: The problem is that this solution is FAR less readable. I glanced at the switch/case statement and instantly knew what it was doing. This one took me a few seconds of doing mental arithmetic. The more thinking is necessary to understand your code, the more likely the next maintainer will break it.

Answer (score 3):

Which one would you prefer? It is your code.

I definitely prefer the switch-case, but if you have something combined or e.g. 'greater than' switch-case is not the right way to do it.

Another thing: I would write the switch case like the following, because I think it is better to read:

```
switch(day){
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        System.out.println("1st Quarter");
        break;
...        
}
```

HTH, Andreas

Answer (score 3):

- Avoid the need for the logic to branch in the first place. Table lookup is often a useful technique. Arithmetic manipulation is also important - look for a pattern in the values you care about, and a function that transforms them into something simpler. Also consider polymorphism in more complex cases.
- If you are handling all the exceptions the same way, then do it in the same place.
- Scope variables tightly where possible.
- Prompt for the input you actually want, FFS. :)

`import java.io.*;`

```
public class Quarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Input the month number (1 = January, 2 = February ... 12 = December): ");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int month = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            int quarter = (month - 1) / 3;
            String[] quarters = new String[]{ "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th" };
            System.out.println(quarters[quarter] + " Quarter");
        } catch (Exception e) { // IOException for non-numeric, or AIOOBE for out of range
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
(day>=1 && day <=3) ? System.out.println("1st Quarter") :
  (day >= 4 && day <= 6) ? System.out.println("2nd Quarter") :
    (day >=7 && day <= 9) ? System.out.println("3rd Quarter") :
      (day >= 10 && day <= 12) ? System.out.println("4th Quarter") : System.out.println("Error1");
```

;)

You could also do this:

```
String val = (day>=1 && day <=3) ? "1st Quarter" :
      (day >= 4 && day <= 6) ? "2nd Quarter" :
        (day >=7 && day <= 9) ? "3rd Quarter" :
          (day >= 10 && day <= 12) ? "4th Quarter" : "Error1";
System.out.println(val);
```

I think either should work.

Comment: how do i replace that with my current code?

Comment: Either one above should work.  Ternary operators can either set values or evaluate.

Comment: That's what's cool about this site.  You ask a pretty basic question and you get a bunch of interesting ways to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me if the question is about solutions to the specific code example, or about the structure in general.  So, some virtues of the if-else approach for consideration.

- if-else is more common in code overall, because the number of
  datatypes accepted by switch is limited and switch itself is limited
  to compile time values.  More familiar is better for readability for
  a broader audience.
- The fundamental structure doesn't change if you find your
  requirements changing and you need to support a different datatype. 
  I've had to change plenty of switches on enums to string compares in
  my time when someone added a requirement that the users be able to
  configure the options.
- The need to use break; properly inside switches introduces
  opportunities for odd bugs that only show up in corner cases as the
  switches grow large and complicated.

Of course personally being an enterprise programmer I would have created a timeUnitSubDivisionResolvingVisitor ... :)

Comment: >"The need to use break; properly inside switches introduces opportunities for odd bugs"        is no longer the case for new switch with Lamba

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] suffix = new String[]{ "st", "nd", "rd", "th" };
System.out.println((1 <= day && day <= 12)?
    String.format("%d%s Quarter", (day-1)/3+1, suffix[(day-1)/3]):
    "Error!"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

just an alternative way of implementing it is through a Map. It will make it configurable especially is you're using Spring where you can have this Map variable setup in your bean.xml if you decide to.

Anyway here is the alternative:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
m.put(1, "1st Quarter");
m.put(2, "1st Quarter");
m.put(3, "1st Quarter");
m.put(4, "2nd Quarter");
m.put(5, "2nd Quarter");
m.put(6, "2nd Quarter");
m.put(7, "3rd Quarter");
m.put(8, "3rd Quarter");
m.put(9, "3rd Quarter");
m.put(10, "4th Quarter");
m.put(11, "4th Quarter");
m.put(12, "4th Quarter");

System.out.println(m.get(d));
```