# Using Strings as switch parameter

Tags: java, switch-statement

I read in an article on **Switch vs If** that if we use String as switch parameter,the compiler will not make a jump table. Is this correct and if yes, pleas explain why?

Thanks

**PS**

I'm more interested in knowing this regarding java. And the part I read about this is from an answer here in Stackoverflow. So here's the link  [stackoverflow.com/a/395965/1043937](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395965/1043937)

It says about c#, but since java also has the same feature since 1.7, Can someone please explain.

Comment: This issue is very different in Java and C. Please specify which language you meant.

Comment: Regarding Java: http://stackoverflow.com/q/338206/50079

Comment: Read @Jon's link. That answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch statements in C cannot accept strings as parameters.

Switch statements on strings in java are available since java 1.7. They weren't before as this block was modeled from the c feature. The fact that java uses, or not, a jump table is implementation dependent and the result also depends on the values.

Edit : for details about the implementation, refer to [the link provided by Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Prior to java 1.7 you can't use string as switch parameter. This is a feature in java 1.7 that you can also use String as switch parameter .

Comment: -1 The question is asking if _the compiler will not make a jump table. Is this correct and if yes, pleas explain why?_

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements work either with primitive types or enumerated types. Java 7 introduced another type that we can use in Switch statements: the String type.

public void process(Trade t) {

```
        String status = t.getStatus();



        switch (status) {

        case NEW:

              newTrade(t);

              break;

        case EXECUTE:

              executeTrade(t);

              break;

        case PENDING:

              pendingTrade(t);

              break;



        default:

              break;

        }

  }
```