# Does C# have an easy way for me to replace multiple if statements?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (testQuestion.Result == "t") { testQuestion.CorrectCount++; }
if (testQuestion.Result == "f") { testQuestion.IncorrectCount--; }
if (testQuestion.Result == "s") { testQuestion.ShownCount++; }
```

Is there a way I can remove the need for the three if statements ?

Comment: You can use [`switch` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) instead of multiple if statements. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-using-if-else-and-switch-case-in-c

Comment: Can you switch on a string in c#? (Granted: you could switch on a character in this case though)

Comment: Actually you can switch strings in C#.

Comment: Is your `Result` property of type `Char` or `String`?

Comment: @Crono double quote warrants a string type,  isn't it? Curious to what you would suggest if char?

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia indeed it does, but since values being checked are one-char only I would have suggested to change `Result` property into a `Char` instead. Not that it will be *that* much more efficient but still, for the sake of best practices, and since the OP is obviously learning the language... thought it might be useful advice. :)

Comment: @Crono ahaa right, indeed a valuable suggestion on choosing right type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C# allows switching strings, you could use switch statements as follows:

```
switch (testQuestion.Result) {
    case "t": testQuestion.CorrectCount++; break;
    case "f": testQuestion.IncorrectCount--; break;
    case "s": testQuestion.ShownCount++; break;
}
```

You can find more details about the switch statements in C# [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx).

Comment: It will result in a compiler error if a break is missing. C# only allow fallthrough if the case is empty.

Comment: I think switch statement would be better if it were inside a method of the class such as testquestion.ProcessResult().

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement:

```
switch (testQuestion.Result)
{
    case "t":
        testQuestion.CorrectCount++;
        break;
    case "f":
        testQuestion. IncorrectCount--;
        break;
    case "s":
        testQuestion.ShowCount++;
        break;
    default:
        // Result is a different value from what's expected
}
```

Or, if you prefer a more compact formula:

```
var q = testQuestion;
switch (q.Result)
{
    case "t": q.CorrectCount++; break;
    case "f": q. IncorrectCount--; break;
    case "s": q.ShowCount++; break;
}
```

I should mention though that if your `Result` property is of type `Char` then you should use apostrophes rather than quotation marks around your values.

**EDIT:** you may also want to have a `default` statement to handle unexpected cases. I just added it to the first block of code above.

Comment: I think switch statement would be better if it were inside a method of the class such as testquestion.ProcessResult().

Comment: @ChadMcGrath actually I think the `Question` should be just that: a question. It shouldn't be responsible for tracking apparitions and good or bad answers. But at this point it's up to the OP to decide what's best. :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
testQuestion.CorrectCount += (testQuestion.Result == "t"? 1 : 0);
testQuestion.IncorrectCount += (testQuestion.Result == "f"? -1 : 0);
testQuestion.ShownCount += (testQuestion.Result == "s"? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: @Bathsheba why do you say so ? when it is about finding out the options why would you say no to an option ?

Comment: @GrantWinney it will work and it works , i dont see your point why you say it wont work

Comment: @GrantWinney well user isnt asking about making it more readable, to me i dont like multiple lines of switch case.

Comment: Exactly. OP asked for an alternative way, and this is one. Not one I would choose but one nonetheless. So it's a valid answer.

Comment: Now that this is more than a single answer; I've retracted my downvote. Infact, it's an alternative now, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 2**

You can wrap the logic in property as in this code.
IMO, this is bit more readable.

```
public class TestQuestion
{
    private string _result;
    public string Result
    {
        get
        {
            return _result;
        }
        set
        {
            _result = value;
            this.CorrectCount += (this._result == Meta.correctResult ? Meta.incrementCount: 0);
            this.IncorrectCount += (this._result == Meta.incorrectResult ? Meta.decrementCount : 0);
            this.ShownCount += (this._result == Meta.shownResult ? Meta.incrementCount : 0);
        }
    }
    public int CorrectCount;
    public int IncorrectCount;
    public int ShownCount;
}
```

Here is code for Meta
, this makes it easy to configure and control at one place.

```
public class Meta
{
    public static  string correctResult = "t";
    public static string incorrectResult = "f";
    public static string shownResult = "s";
    public static int incrementCount = 1;
    public static int decrementCount = -1;
}
```

This is how I used it in LinqPad

```
void Main()
{
    TestQuestion testQuestion = new TestQuestion();
    testQuestion.Result = "t";  
    testQuestion.Result = "f";  
    testQuestion.Result = "s";
    testQuestion.Dump();

}
```

Isn't it more readable ?

Comment: I strongly disagree with this design. Setting the `Result` property more than once - even with the same value - may completely unbalance increments.

Comment: @Crono you don't agree to design ? or you think use of design that might end up in unwanted result ?

think of 2 ways , 1) what if business requirement says update the counter every-time value is assigned ?  2) updated the counter only when required and independent of value assignment (this is what i think you are referring )

what you think ? isn't that depends .

lastly to be clear, intention here is to share views, learn and grow.  No where I am intending  to take sides of above answer.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your last statement and this is why I haven't voted this answer down, because regardless of what I think of the design that *might* still work (although I don't see why you'd set three different `Result` values in the `Main` method consecutively???). That being said, I still see lots of code smells in this - enough so that the OP should feel concerned about doing something like this. Your other answer wasn't perfect either but I still much prefer it over that one.

Comment: use in main is just for demo that we kind of get away from if in main stream and they are in side the class..

Comment: i would wish to setup some time to go over with you on what you think is better / best answer and why ? also discuss the code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Though late to the party, still few cents from me.
Create a lookup through dictionary `Dictionary<string,Action>` with string value as key and the various operations in the action delegate. Then initialize that lookup in constructor.
Below is the sample code.

```
 public class Example
 {
     private static Dictionary<string,Action> _lookup=new();
     private static void Init(TestQuestion testQuestion)
     {
         _lookup.Add("t",()=> testQuestion.CorrectCount++);
         _lookup.Add("f",()=> testQuestion.InCorrectCount--);
         _lookup.Add("s",()=> testQuestion.ShownCount++);
      }
      public void ExampleMethod(TestQuestion testQuestion)
      {
             Init(testQuestion);
             _lookup[testQuestion.Result]();    // this pull the matching action and execute with `()` added 
      }
}
```

This is a sample, in actual this lookup should be moved in separate class.
The above code does away with `multiple if-else`