# Swift iOS -Does A Class Object Type Consume More Memory Then A "Primitive" Type?

Tags: swift, class, memory, struct, primitive

I know in Swift primitives don't exist but it was the best name I could think of.

I went to a Meetup a couple of weeks ago and the speaker said that a Switch statement consumes slightly more memory then an If-Else statement. I had no idea there was a difference in memory consumption between the 2 and if I had thought about it I would've thought the opposite. Anyway it got me to thinking about my code.

I'm sending data from one vc to another and I can do it 2 different ways.

1. I can send 2 variables with a value from ClassA to ClassB
2. I can create a class or struct model that has the same 2 variables as properties and then pass the model from ClassA to ClassB

1st example:

```
ClassA:UIViewController{

var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?

viewDidLoad...{

    self.firstName = "Veggie"
    self.lastName = "Burger"
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "..."{

              let classB = segue.destination...
              classB.firstName = self.firstName
              classB.lastName = self.lastName
        }
}

ClassB:UIViewController{

var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?

viewDidLoad...{

     self.firstName! ... //do something with it
     self.lastName! ... //do something with it
}
}
```

2nd Example:

```
class: Person{
     firstName: String?
     lastName: String?
}


ClassA:UIViewController{

var person: Person?

viewDidLoad...{

    self.person = Person()
    self.person.firstName = "Veggie"
    self.person.lastName = "Burger"
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "..."{

              let classB = segue.destination...
              classB.person = self.person
        }
}

ClassB:UIViewController{

var person: Person?

viewDidLoad...{

     self.person.firstName! ... //do something with it
     self.person.lastName! ... //do something with it
}
}
```

I know in the 1st example I have 2 different values sitting at 2 different memory addresses but in the 2nd example I have 1 value sitting at 1 memory address. I'm unsure if it's properties are also sitting at 2 different memory addresses or sharing the same one.

Would the 1st example or the 2nd example consume more memory?

Comment: `Switch statement consumes slightly more memory then an If-Else statement` I don't see why this would be, assuming both variants are doing the same thing.

Comment: @Alexander Those aren't my words I'm just repeating what the speaker said. He wasn't a novice and no one else in the room questioned it. There were some very experienced devs in attendance.

Comment: Has the speaker recorded a video of his presentation? I would like to look into it

Comment: @Alexander I don't remember the organizer recording it. I found some info on the speaker/dev though. His name is Anton Doudarev and he created JSONModelKit (that's what the talk was on). https://github.com/antonthedev

Comment: Switch statements involve more complex pattern matching, optimized by the compiler. `If-else` is just simple boolean evaluation. Basically, a Switch has a matrix it uses to evaluate a variable and immediately go to the correct case. thus it uses more memory than an if-else (which is more/less imperative and etherial) but has a meaningful performance and syntactic improvement.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ thanks for the clarity. I didn't know why a switch consumed more. I found out at a Meetup and it was something the speaker said while explaining something else. It was sitting on my mind.

Comment: @Alexander Peejweej just explained why a switch statement consumes more memory.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ There are definitely cases in which switch statements *can* consume more memory, because they can do things regular `if` statements can't. I'm talking about the (typical) case in which you have two pieces of code doing the same thing, one that uses a switch case with simple cases that are looking to match an exact value, vs one that uses a ladder of if-else statements. They would compile to the exact same machine code

Comment: @Alexander I'm almost sure that's not true. A switch statement doesn't simply look at each case, evaluate it, then look at the next one. This is hard to search for, but here's some information based on C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-using-if-else-and-switch-case-in-c

Comment: Summation being, The compiler (in some cases) can create a hash table with the Switch cases and match the variable to go to the correct line, a REALLY smart compiler could potentially do the same thing with if-else. I don't know enough about the Swift compiler to know if this is done.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Yeah I'm not sure about the swift compiler in particular, but I've looked into this in the case of java, and `if`/`else` statements that emulate switches are picked up and optimized to be equivalent to a `switch`.

Comment: @Alexander That makes sense. JIT compiling obviously has pretty different constraints, but it wouldn't surprise me if Swift has something like that. Either way, if you want to guarantee the performance you can use the Switch :)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ This can be statically deduced, as well. In fact, IntelliJ Idea offers a fix-it that lets you automatically rewrite an `if`/`else if`/`else` ladder into a `switch` whenever possible (according to Java's really constrained `switch`'s capabilities)

Comment: @Alexander Man am I glad Swift has more capable switches...but yeah, this can probably be tested pretty easily as well. Swift is still pretty young so it's possible these type of smaller optimizations haven't yet been implemented. If only I was a compiler engineer :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151533/discussion-between-alexander-and-peejweej).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects (instances of classes) have two machine words of overhead. One which points to the meta class object (which contains all the various information about the object's instance variables, properties, methods, etc.), and another word which contains the reference count and other booking keep data for the object.

The overhead of these two fields isn't usually. Of course, if you're making lots (100,000s) of small objects, the penalty adds up. And if your object only contains one machine word of real data, but has 2 words of overhead, you're only getting 33% utilization from the memory. The bigger issue is that objects are allocated on the heap, which is an expensive process. Further more, creating destroying references to objects requires synchronized modification of the objects reference count.

Structs store their fields inline, and instances of structs are stored on the stack. They're incredibly efficient and highly optimizable by the compiler. In most cases, with whole module optimization enabled, most structs don't even exist at runtime, as the compiler is able to just work with the data within them directly. They so efficient, in fact, that everything you might think of as a "primitive" (from a language like Java) is actually implemented as a struct (or maybe an `enum`, which is similar). For example, `Int` (and `(U)Int8/16/32/64`), `Character`, etc. are all structs.

But importantly, none of this really matters. Until you've identified a performance issue, you're wasting your time by letting irrelevant factors dictate your code, at the expense of other probably more important factors (readability, maintainability, brevity, etc.).

If you need to repeatedly deal with pairs of first names and last name, *by all means*, go ahead and make a `Person` struct that stores first and last names. That's the *point* of types. To lift you up form the bit and bytes and bring you to a higher, simpler, level of thinking about your code.

I would highly recommend you check out [Do iOS 2016 - Rob Napier, Once more, with types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg), a great talk by [@RobNapier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier)

Comment: The other aspect that should be remembered is what you're giving up in memory you're losing in performance. It's faster to pass an already created variable (by value or reference) than to set multiple different variables

Answer (score 1):

Memory usage should be similar and even if there is a small difference, it doesn't really matter unless you're creating millions of instances.

I would prefer the second example, as related fields (firstName, lastName) are encapsulated. This allows you to add methods to Person, which would otherwise reside in your view controller code leading to a god classes and making your code less testable.

Comment: thanks for the help. I know that it's minuscule but I would still like to know which one consumes more memory. I also could've spun what I mentioned at the bottom about the instance's 2 properties sitting at different addresses or the same address as the instance into a different question but it was simpler to add it here.

Comment: I agree with Palle. I would add that Person is a reference type in the second example. If you make any changes to it in the segue controller, then the original controller will get them too. For your model, this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @JeremiahJessel thanks for the help. I know it makes more sense and readability is better. I just wanted to know which consumed more memory considering a switch consumes more then an if-else.

Comment: @LanceSamaria Even if a `switch` statement used more memory than an `if`/`else` (I'm very skeptical), that should not at all motivate your use of an `if`/`else` until you've reached a point where you're certain that there's a measured, real, memory footprint reduction that is necessary for your program. You have to understand that even though `switch` statements and `if`/`else` statements can do the same things, they *mean* very different things

Comment: @Alexander why would they mean very different things even though they do the sane thing? I perceive them as conditionals and switch statements being more "compact". Almost like if key vs guard. I know with guard you can still access the constant outside it's code (or something along those lines)  but the main purpose is to safely unwrap something. I'd think if-else & switch main purpose/meaning is to test conditions?

Comment: @Alexander I meant "if let" not "if key". Autocorrect mistake and too late to edit

Comment: @LanceSamaria A `switch` statement is a control flow statement that focuses on the value of a single variable (or tuple), and responds depending on what case it is. This *can* be done purely with `if`/`else` statements, but it *shouldn't*. `if`/`else` statements are control flow statements that you should use when you're checking multiple different variables independently of each other

Comment: @LanceSamaria Consider a HTTP status code. It's a single variable, which can have multiple different values you want to handle differently. This can be done with a `if`/`else if`/`else` ladder, but it shouldn't, because `switch` is a more appropriate choice. It communicates across that each of the cases are all contingent on a single piece of data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151523/discussion-between-alexander-and-lance-samaria).