# if-else case or switch case or ternary operator which one to use if i am having 10 string conditions

Tags: java, performance

I want a better performing code. I have used so many if-else in my code. I want to reduce the lines of code and increase the performance. Please suggest.

Comment: Well we'd have to see the code to be able to give any advice. Although if you have ten if else cases, I would highly recommend not using a nested ternary operator for that

Comment: "better performing code" and "reduce the lines of code" are not the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any significant difference between using if/else and switch-case in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-using-if-else-and-switch-case-in-c)

Comment: If "reduce the lines of code" is your goal, you're doing it wrong.  Reducing the number of lines of code just to reduce the number of lines of code should **NEVER** be a goal.

Comment: You seem to know about `switch`, so why not give that a try?

Comment: @AniketKariya Closing a Java question as a duplicate of a C# question is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The performance it's almost the same in all cases. What you have to look it's for legibility, and with so many conditions you will be better with an switch statement.