# Dart switch statement - Case expressions must be constant

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I looked at a few questions regarding this for other languages and some suggest using `final` but that doesn't seem to work with Dart.

I'm passing in arguments so surely the switch statement cannot contain constants only? A switch statement, much like an if statement is asking *if* it is or not..ie it's unknown so I don't see how a switch statement can be useful if they have to be constants...?

```
  setCategory(arga, argb) {
    int result;
    switch (true) {
      case (arga >= 0 && arga < 3 && argb < 35):
        result = 16;
        break;
      case (arga >= 0 && arga < 3 && argb >= 35):
        result = 15;
        break;
        etc
```

It's returning the error `Case expressions must be constant` regarding the values arga and argb in the case expressions. What's the best way to remedy this or do I have to use an if statement?

Comment: I think you should use if-else for such cases, you also can try to optimise your problem using math (some cases can be simplified or nested)

Comment: There are many cases - 16 in fact, I learnt that in  this kind of situation it's not good to use if-else. If-else is better when there are just a few cases.

Comment: Yes, when your cases are constant values, not expressions.

Comment: @Ammar Atef So you can only use ONE expression?

Comment: Yes, `switch(the expression goes here){ case CONSTANT: ...`

Comment: Ok so switch statements are pretty useless in dart.

Comment: @Hasen Traditionally `switch` cases must be constants in most C-based languages (C, C++, Java, ...).  The are not useless; they offer an optimization opportunity (using a jumptable instead of a sequence of branches), they offer a debugging opportunity (in some cases, the compiler can warn if there are unhandled cases), and they can provide clearer code structure.  Also see [Is there any significant difference between using if/else and switch-case in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-using-if-else-and-switch-case-in-c)

Comment: Additionally, I would actually argue that the way you want to use arbitrary expressions as `switch` cases would make them useless since they then would offer very little benefit over `if`-`else`.

Answer (score 19):

The switch case expressions must be constants for sure.

You have to use `if`/`then` chains to do multiple tests based on non-constant values.

You cannot use arguments from the surrounding function in a switch case. What you are trying to do here is not supported by the Dart switch statement.

The Dart switch statement is deliberately kept very simple, so that a compiler can know all the possible cases at compile-time. That's why they must be compile-time constants.

Switch statements are still useful for some kinds of switching, like on enums:

```
enum Nonse { foo, bar, baz; }

String fooText(Nonse non) {
  switch (non) {
    case Nonse.foo: return "foo";
    case Nonse.bar: return "bar";
    case Nonse.baz: return "baz";
  }
  throw ArgumentError.notNull("non");
}
```

You can also switch over constant string values or integer values.

Comment: Do you know how to work with enum extension too?

Comment: Extension methods on an enum type works just like extension methods on any other type. You can't make extensions on individual values, so you'll still have to switch on the `this` value. So, nothing different about that for this question.

Answer (score 6):

There are some rules for Switch Case

> The default case is optional.
>
> All case expression must be unique.
>
> The case statements can include only constants. It cannot be a variable or an expression.
>
> The data type of the variable and the case expression must match.
>
> There can be any number of case statements within a switch.

you should use 'If Else' statement

Comment: Actually its not useless but you are using it wrongly.

Comment: Constant values never change...I don't see the point in asking about them in a switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statement requires a constant -> it means already initialized variable with final value

```
switch (expression) {
  case ONE : {
      statement(s);
  }
  break;
  case TWO: {
      statement(s);
  }
  break;
  default : {
      statement(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int x=0; x<1; x++){
if(ing5<8 && toWhatDegreeRand<=10 && toWhatDegreeRand>7){
  toWhatDegreeRand=9;
}
if(ing4<8 && toWhatDegreeRand<=7 && toWhatDegreeRand>5){
  toWhatDegreeRand=6;
}
if(ing3<8 && toWhatDegreeRand<=5 && toWhatDegreeRand>3){
  toWhatDegreeRand=4;
}//....
```

}

It can be a little useful.