# how do i change background colors based on current one by using a switch

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

so i am trying to change the background color based on the current color by using a switch however iam getting an error.

```
switch (BtnColor.BackgroundColor)
            {
                case Color.Red:
                    BtnColor.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                    break;
                case Color.White:
                    BtnColor.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
                    break;
                default:
                    BtnColor.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
            }
```

i am getting the following error on: `case Color.White:` and `case Color.Red:`

> A constant value is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors are not constants, and that's what you're supposed to use when using Switch statements.

Predefined Colors are Static Properties of the Color class, so that can't be used.

[image: Sample Color Definition]

In this case you can use if/then/else statements to achieve the same exact thing.

Also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395965/5935720)