# I want to read cells color in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to read `BackColor` of cells with the below function,that returns me double type values. I need to read the values for 25 Cells, but it takes too much time to read all these cells (to exclude the code). And then I need to set that color as `BackColor` of TextBoxes. I am using **Interop Library**. Is it possible to reduce this delay of reading the BackColor of the cells?

The problem is accessing the cell.  `GetColor()` its not the problem. Its just that it takes too much time to read values from the cell.

```
var colorCode = ws.Cells[i, objectHeading].Interior.Color;
```

```
public Color GetColor(int i, double colorCode)
{
    if (colorCode == 12566463)
        return Color.LightGray;
    else if (colorCode == 65535)
        return Color.Yellow;
    else if (colorCode == 3394611 || colorCode == 5296274)
        return Color.LightGreen;
    else if (colorCode == 49407)
        return Color.Orange;
    else if (colorCode == 15773696)
        return Color.LightBlue;
    else
        return Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `switch` statement? More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

Comment: @Rron Frangu: Try to measure code performance: what takes too much time, accessing the cell or the `GetColor()` method? If it is the `GetColor()` then try to check using the `HashTable`. The `switch-case` translated by compiler to the same `if-else`: therefore does not help much. See [Is there any significant difference between using if/else and switch-case in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395618/6630084)

Comment: Make sure to not do page updates as you change the colors. `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = false; `

Comment: The problem is accessing the cell. >GetColor its not the real problem. Its just that it takes too much time to read values from the cell.