# Better way of writing if else conditions

Tags: coding-style

The code runs like this, as the code increases it becomes unreadable

```
if(!cond1){
    //print error
}else{
        if(!cond2){
          // print error
        }else{
               //code goes on.....
             }
     }
```

Alternative way of writing the above code will be very helpful

Comment: It depends on language and larger context. "Not Constructive". (I prefer to avoid needless nested `if` statements, though .. C-style languages have the hanging `else if` construct.)

Comment: Possibly look at using a switch case if appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/395618/609908 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/335971/609908

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to understand/debug if you use the blocks to execute the true conditions. It is because when *something is true* is a narrower condition than when something is *not* true.

```
if (cond1){

}else if (cond2){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually handled with [guard clauses](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) instead of nested or chained `if`s:

```
if (! cond1)
    throw error 1;
if (! cond2)
    throw error 2;

perform action;
```

Note that this assumes that the function actually *returns* upon error, otherwise this will lead to faulty behaviour. However, this is *recommended*. In general, don’t try to resume an action in the face of errors, yield control to a higher level in your application’s logic as soon as possible.

In particular, the “print error” aspect should almost (?) *always* be disconnected from the actual logic – otherwise you are violating the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

As a consequence, let your logic-performing function exit early when an error condition is detected, and let other functions take care of printing those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the complexity, you might consider breaking conditions up into their own functions, and restructuring into something like:

```
if (!f1() && !f2() ... ){
    ...
}
```

Then let each individual condition's function handle that particular error instead of cluttering up the top-level function.